# How to dynamically define functions?

Tags: python

I have functions like this:

```
def activate_field_1():
   print 1

def activate_field_2():
   print 2

def activate_field_3():
   print 3
```

How do I define `activate_field_[x]` for `x=1:10`, without typing out each one of them? I'd much rather pass a parameter, of course, but for my purposes this is not possible.

Comment: You say in a comment that you want to define them statically but then you mention that doing so will waste space in the source file. Which is it?

Comment: What is a "dynamic function"? Can you explain the intended meaning of this phrase?

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291242/python-dynamically-create-function-at-runtime

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do you want to define these individually in your source file, statically? Then your best option would be to write a script to generate them.

If on the other hand you want these functions at runtime you can use a higher order function. For e.g.

```
>>> def make_func(value_to_print):
...     def _function():
...         print value_to_print
...     return _function
...
>>> f1 = make_func(1)
>>> f1()
1
>>> f2 = make_func(2)
>>> f2()
2
```

You can generate a list of these and store, again at runtime.

```
>>> my_functions = [make_func(i) for i in range(1, 11)]
>>> for each in my_functions:
...     each()
...
1
2
3
...
```

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to define them statically in the source file. I can script them, though so many functions wastes space. Thanks for the explanation on how to do it at runtime.

Answer (score 12):

Here's something that produces function names *exactly* like you wanted (and is a little simpler than the [Dynamic/runtime method creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533382/dynamic-runtime-method-creation-code-generation-in-python)'s [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/534597/355230) mentioned in @Goutham's now deleted answer):

```
FUNC_TEMPLATE = """def activate_field_{0}(): print({0})"""
for x in range(1, 11): exec(FUNC_TEMPLATE.format(x))

>>> activate_field_1()
1
>>> activate_field_7()
7
```

In Python versions 3.6+, it can be written as shown below using so-called [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) literals:

```
for x in range(1, 11): exec(f"""def activate_field_{x}(): print({x})""")
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to dynamically generate test case functions for unit testing, thanks.

Comment: This was very nice, I was able to define functions with decorators too.

Comment: Good to remember that this approach is not suitable for production code.

Comment: @JourdanRodrigues why not? Anything that works is suitable.

Answer (score 5):

You may put new symbols into the dictionary of current variable bindings returned by `vars()`:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    def f(x):
        def g():
            print x
        return g
    vars()['activate_field_%d' % i] = f(i)

>>> activate_field_3()
3
```

But this trick is generally not recommented unless you definitely sure you need it.

Comment: You really _don't_ need to [re]define `f()` 10 times…

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could adapt this recipe for your needs.

```
from functools import partial
class FunctionPool:
    def __init__(self,function):
        self.function = function
    def __getitem__(self,item):
        return partial(self.function,item)

>>> @FunctionPool
def func(item,param):
    print "function#{item} called with {param}".format(
        item = item,
        param = param )
>>> f = func[2]
>>> f(3)
function#2 called with 3
```