# Python: dynamically create function at runtime

Tags: python, function, runtime

How to dynamically create a function in Python?

I saw a few answers here but I couldn't find one which would describe the most general case.

Consider:

```
def a(x):
    return x + 1
```

How to create such function on-the-fly? Do I have to `compile('...', 'name', 'exec')` it? But what then? Creating a dummy function and replacing its code object for then one from the compile step?

Or should I use `types.FunctionType`? How?

I would like to customize everything: number of argument, their content, code in function body, the result, ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [True dynamic and anonymous functions possible in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303248/true-dynamic-and-anonymous-functions-possible-in-python)

Comment: I don't think it a duplicate: `dynf = FunctionType(compile('def f(x): return x + 3', 'dyn.py', 'exec'), globals())` and `print dynf(1)` breaks with `TypeError: '<module>() takes no arguments (1 given)'`

Comment: Just because the answer there might be wrong doesn't mean this isn't a duplicate question.

Comment: The linked question has an updated answer demonstrating how to create a function with arguments.

Comment: are you sure you can't achieve what you want using functional programming as it exists in python (lambdas, closures, compositions...)? the code objects are fiddly, and they're not well documented (or really at all). Plus they're considered internals, subject to change with or without notice.

Answer (score 44):

Use `exec`:

```
>>> exec("""def a(x):
...   return x+1""")
>>> a(2)
3
```

Comment: if anyone gets `NameError` consider using `locals().get('a')

Comment: given the option of safer alternatives, I think this answer should come with an appropriate warning

Answer (score 40):

Did you see [this](http://snipplr.com/view/17819/), its an example which tells you how to use `types.FunctionType`

**Example:**

```
import types

def create_function(name, args):
    def y(): pass

    y_code = types.CodeType(args,
                            y.func_code.co_nlocals,
                            y.func_code.co_stacksize,
                            y.func_code.co_flags,
                            y.func_code.co_code,
                            y.func_code.co_consts,
                            y.func_code.co_names,
                            y.func_code.co_varnames,
                            y.func_code.co_filename,
                            name,
                            y.func_code.co_firstlineno,
                            y.func_code.co_lnotab)

    return types.FunctionType(y_code, y.func_globals, name)

myfunc = create_function('myfunc', 3)

print repr(myfunc)
print myfunc.func_name
print myfunc.func_code.co_argcount

myfunc(1,2,3,4)
# TypeError: myfunc() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: Yes, I saw it and it seems to be exactly what I'm after. But I don't know how to create/modify function body and return values..?

Comment: I just tryed it, when you change the call at the end with the correct nb of args, it segfault...

Comment: Did you ever try to execute this code? Because this code can't run.

Comment: yeah `func_Code` attribute doesn't exist in python 3.

Comment: The original post said, "Did you see [this](http://snipplr.com/view/17819/)?". However, the original webpage is dead now. There is no [http://snipplr.com/view/17819/](http://snipplr.com/view/17819/).

Comment: Link was for reference, bu you can get an idea from example pasted above.

Answer (score 32):

If you need to dynamically create a function from a certain template try this piece:

```
def create_a_function(*args, **kwargs):

    def function_template(*args, **kwargs):
        pass

    return function_template

my_new_function = create_a_function()
```

Within function *create_a_function()* you can control, which template to chose. The inner function *function_template* serves as template. The return value of the creator function is a function. After assignment you use *my_new_function* as a regular function.

Typically, this pattern is used for function decorators, but might by handy here, too.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. My use case was to create a function based on one of my dynamic generated class attribute. But it should not depend on 'self'. Therefore it is a static func `create_a_function` with the parameter as an argument. Thereby the attribute can be used in the inner function as a normal variable and the function is detached :-)

Comment: it has some limit, can't be serialized by pickle

Answer (score 14):

You can use lambda for this.

```
a = lambda x: x + 1
>>> a(2)
3
```

Comment: This is almost the one I'm using now. In my case I need to dynamically build a function as a string or to precompile a configured string expression, so I used `a = eval("lambda x: x + 1")` instead, but the result is the same. In my case I also provide math functions to expressions, so I also added `from math import *` in the python scripts that evaluate and execute the lambda.

Comment: Note that you can use this to create a list or dict of functions that can be run like `generic['d'](3)`

Answer (score 9):

What about this approach?

In this example I'm *parametrizing* first order functions on one variable (x -> ax+b) in one class:

```
class Fun: 
  def __init__(self, a,b):
    self.a, self.b = a,b

  def f(self, x):
    return (x*self.a + self.b)

 u = Fun(2,3).f
```

Here  `u`  will be the function x->2x+3.

Comment: there's always `functools.partial` applied to lambdas as well: `u = partial(lambda a, b, x: x*a + b, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do at this manner:

```
new_func='def next_element(x):\n  return x+1'
the_code=compile(new_func,'test','exec')
exec(the_code)
next_element(1)
```

It's similar to the previous exec solution.

Answer (score 1):

simpler than Berci's answer

```py
def get_fn(a, b): # factory function
  def fn(): # result function
    print(a, b)
  return fn

fn = get_fn(1, 2)

fn()
```

this is useful to turn variables into constants ("template variables for dynamic functions")

Answer (score 1):

In my case I need a function returning the function to save it into a variable:

```
def create_function(function_name, function_arguments, function_code):
    function_string = f"def {function_name}({function_arguments}): {function_code}"
    exec(function_string)
    return_value = eval(function_name)
    return return_value

name = 'say_hello'
arguments = 'name'
code = 'print(f"Hello, {name}!")'

myfunc = create_function(name, arguments, code)

print(myfunc, type(myfunc))
myfunc('John Doe')
```

Answer (score 1):

for the sake of completeness, the way how dynamically created function works can be simply parametrized

```
def dynamically_create_greeting(greet_style):
    def inner(name):
        print(f'{greet_style} {name}')

    return inner


say_hello = dynamically_create_greeting(greet_style='hello')
say_hello('John')

say_hi = dynamically_create_greeting(greet_style='hi')
say_hi('John')
```

this produces output >

hello John

hi John

Comment: Hi, can you explain, how it works? It looks like the greet_style parameter is passed to the function before it's called, what is the explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Note these are separate functions and parameters. First is dynamically_create_greeting() function, and you pass the 'greet_style' in there as a parameter. That will just dynamically create (without executing it) inner function what will behave based on that parameter, and returns it. In the example above we will refer to  the returned functions using  'say_hello' and 'say_hi'. Then, you actually call (execute) say_hello() itself, what accepts it's own parameter - 'name'.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the functions are created dynamically. What I don't understand is how  and where the "greet_style" parameter is stored. Because when we call say_hello and say_hi, we pass only the name but not the greet_style.

Comment: It's not stored in a sense of a an object having member you can interact with or change. You create a function and it behaves in some way, it does 'something'. So you create it (dynamically in this case) with how to do 'something' built-in.  It's 'stored' in the same way as print function behavior to display smt on a console is 'stored' somewhere so print does exactly that and not something else ( if that's where are you heading, your function behavior ("greet_style) is 'stored' somewhere in your active python session's memory, look for 'inspect' module for this low level operations)