# How can I define function names with variable contents in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

Basically, what I want to do is this:

```
for i in range(10):
  def function[i_value]():
    pass
```

Which would define these functions: function0, function1, ..., function9.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291242/python-dynamically-create-function-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

If these functions are going to be a single-line expressions-only functions you can use `lambda`:

```
for name in ['func_1', 'func_2']:
    name = lambda: None
```

Though I don't see why you would want to do it, as the functions won't be accessible once the `for` loop is done.

You can store them in a dict though for later access:

```
funcs = {}
for name in ['func_1', 'func_2']
    funcs[name] = lambda: None

print funcs['func_1'] 

>> <function <lambda> at 0x0019B1E0>
```

Comment: I actually don't understand the use of lambda, but thanks for the dict idea!