# Python metaprogramming: generate a function signature with type annotation

Tags: python, metaprogramming, type-hinting

I am working within a Python web framework that uses Python 3 type annotations for validation and dependency injection.

So I am looking for a way to generate functions with type annotations from a parameters given to the generating function:

```
def gen_fn(args: Dict[str, Any]) -> Callable:
    def new_fn(???):
        pass
    return new_fn
```

so that

```
inspect.signature(gen_fn({'a': int}))
```

will return

```
<Signature (a:int)>
```

Is there something I cam put instead of the `???` that will do the thing I need.

I also looked at `Signature.replace()` in the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature.replace) module, but did not find a way to attach the new signature to a new or existing function.

I am hesitant to use [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) because:

> The abstract syntax itself might change with each Python release

So my question is: **What (if any) is a reasonable way to generate a function with Python 3 type annotation based on a `dict` passed to the generating function?**

---

Edit: while [@Aran-Fey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222951/)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385115/110488) answer my question correctly, it appears that my assumption was wrong. Changing the signature doesn't allow calling the `new_fn` using the new signature. That is `gen_fn({'a': int})(a=42)` raises a `TypeError:` ... `got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'.

Comment: I guess one way to achieve that is to build a string and `eval()` the whole string to get the function definition. But I don't think that's the best way to do it.

Comment: [MonkeyType](https://github.com/Instagram/MonkeyType) can generate type annotations for some functions, but it requires the types to be checked at run-time.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of creating a function with annotations, it's easier to create a function and then set the annotations manually.

- [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) looks for the existence of a `__signature__` attribute before it looks at the function's actual signature, so we can craft an appropriate [`inspect.Signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature) object and assign it there:

  ```
  params = [inspect.Parameter(param,
                              inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD,
                              annotation=type_)
                          for param, type_ in args.items()]
  new_fn.__signature__ = inspect.Signature(params)
  ```
- [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) does *not* respect `__signature__`, so we should update the `__annotations__` attribute as well:

  ```
  new_fn.__annotations__ = args
  ```

Putting them both together:

```
def gen_fn(args: Dict[str, Any]) -> Callable:
    def new_fn():
        pass

    params = [inspect.Parameter(param,
                                inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD,
                                annotation=type_)
                            for param, type_ in args.items()]
    new_fn.__signature__ = inspect.Signature(params)
    new_fn.__annotations__ = args

    return new_fn

print(inspect.signature(gen_fn({'a': int})))  # (a:int)
print(get_type_hints(gen_fn({'a': int})))  # {'a': <class 'int'>}
```

---

Note that this doesn't make your function *callable* with these arguments; all of this is just smoke and mirrors that makes the function *look* like it has those parameters and annotations. *Implementing* the function is a separate issue.

You can define the function with [varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) to aggregate all the arguments into a tuple and a dict:

```
def new_fn(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

But that still leaves you with the problem of implementing the function body. You haven't said what the function should do when it's called, so I can't help you with that. You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291242/python-dynamically-create-function-at-runtime) for some pointers.

Comment: This seems to be correct but insufficient for my needs. See `Edit` to the OP.

Comment: @ChenLevy Yes, implementing the function is a separate issue. You can make the function accept arbitrary arguments if you define it as `def new_fn(*args, **kwargs):`, but you still have to implement the function's body. You haven't specified what the function is supposed to do when it's called, so I can't give you much advice. Depending on the circumstances, you may even have to resort the writing code at runtime and then [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)ing it.

Comment: You made my day, sir!