# How to create automatically generated functions with type annotations identifiable by type checkers?

Tags: python, python-typing

Recently I wanted to mimic the inner workings of Python modules like dataclasses and Pydantic's BaseModel. They both manage to automatically create functions (more precisely methods) with certain type annotations that a static type checker can read and suggest upon.

For example, after the creation of the following dataclass

```py
@dataclass
class Test:
    a: int
    b: str
```

an `__init__` method will be created whose `__annotations__ = {"a": int, "b": str}`. This allows MyPy in my case to check whether constructing a `Test` instance is correctly typed.

How can this be done without the use of dataclasses?

The goal is to achieve a way of creating a function where its annotations are supplied. Something like:

```py
annotations = {"parameter": float}

def f(parameter) -> None:
    print(f"f is called with {parameter}")

f.__annotations__ = annotations

f("test")  # MyPy will mark this as an error
```

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384862/python-metaprogramming-generate-a-function-signature-with-type-annotation) I found here - to it a solution exists, but one that static type checkers cannot infer from. Another thing I've tried was reading the implementation of the dataclass module which can be found [here](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses).

Comment: In general, you can't. `dataclass` itself is special-cased by type checkers. The type-checker itself doesn't execute any code, but knowing about `dataclass`, it can "simulate" what `dataclass` does after parsing the `class` statement .

Comment: The type-checker doesn't *use* `__annotations__`; rather the value of the automatically generated `__annotations__` attribute will *agree* with whatever the type-checker itself inferred from the function annotations.