# Dynamically changing the definition of a module and class without changing the module code directly

Tags: python, dynamic

I am not even sure, whether the following is possible.
My question is easily described with the following code.

My module is defined as

```
asdf = 5
class MyClass:
    def myfct(self):
        return asdf
```

I have a module which defines a complex class.
It uses a definition of the module it is in.
Here I call it `asdf`.
In fact, `asdf` is a class definition in itself, I just have it as an integer here for simplicity sake.

I want to remove `asdf` from the module as a member, but still have the class work.
So before deleting it from the module, I first write it into the definition `MyClass` dynamically after loading the module, then I delete it from the module.

```
import mymodule

MyClass.asdf = asdf
del sys.modules['mymodule'].asdf
```

Finally I use this to instantiate the new class

```
myobj = mymodule.MyClass()
myobj.myfct()
```

but of course, this throws the error

> NameError: name 'asdf' is not defined

How can I make the class work without changing the code of the class, namely without changing `return asdf` to `return self.asdf` and but still deleting `asdf` from the module (and not adding other module attributes). However, I am allowed to change the function dynamically after `import mymodule`.

Keep in mind that the function definition is very complex, so something like writing it again with `exec` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11291851/4533188) is not an option.

One idea of mine is to change the signature of the method dynamically such that it receives an optional argument `asdf`. That way, the code inside would use that variable, but I do not know how to do that. Possibly helpfull might be Byteplay/Metaclasses:

- http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2006_12_16.shtml#e583
- https://wiki.python.org/moin/ByteplayDoc
- http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/metaclasses.shtml
- http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/metaclasses-pycon.pdf

Comment: What's the need to delete `mymodule.asdf` at all in the first place? What's wrong with not deleting it and just letting the module work as it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer works, but is semi-great.
Basically we save the original method in a dummy variable `myfct_original`.
Then we redefine our function such that the variable `MyClass.asdf` is copied to the module, the original method is applied, and the variables is removed from the module - so for a short time it is available in the module.

```
asdf = 5
class MyClass:
    def myfct(self, test=1):
        return asdf

MyClass.asdf = asdf
MyClass.myfct_original = MyClass.myfct

del sys.modules[__name__].asdf
delattr(MyClass, 'myfct')

def newmyfct(self, *args, **kwargs):
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'asdf', MyClass.asdf)
    result = MyClass.myfct_original(self, *args, **kwargs)
    del sys.modules[__name__].asdf
    return result

setattr(MyClass, 'myfct', newmyfct)

myobj = MyClass()
myobj.myfct()
```

Maybe someone can do better (see end of the question).