# Dynamically create locust tasks

Tags: http, testing, load-testing, locust

I have a list of api urls to do locust test as input, this list is configurable and changes with user input

```
API_URLS= [
"/api/v2/product",
"/api/v2/order",
"/api/v2/cart",
"/api/v2/users",
.....
]
```

Is there a way I can create locust tasks dynamically/programmatically for above api urls and add them to the `tasks` attribute of HTTPUser or TaskSet before the test runs ?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to dynamically create Locust tasks. I've answered this before here:

[Create locust tasks dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64269703/create-locust-tasks-dynamically)