# Python : Create functions by gitting names from dictionary

Tags: python

I trying to create functions by gitting functions names from giving dictionary,
actually, I'm not sure if this is possible, her is what I'm trying to do:

```
def functions_factory(my_dict):
        for the name in my_dict:
            create_function(name)

def   create_function(function_name):
        x=0
        # **code implentation:** here should write a code that can create function with name = <function_name>
```

Comment: creating variables (in this case functions) like this is never a good idea and a sign that you should take a different approach to your problem. This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3687682/831878 -- but yeah, it's unlikely this is really the right way to go about things. Definitely seems like an XY.

Comment: How would you generate the *body* of the function in a dynamic way? Using a dynamic name for the function seems like the lesser problem compared to the fact that its code will always be the same. As such, this seems very pointless.

Comment: it's very good idea for people who can think out of the box. if you know an answer, add it, if you don't, please leave without philosophizing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
one = 'one'
two = 'two'
three = 'three'
l = {one:1, two:2, three:3}
def some_stuff():
    print("some stuff")
for keys,item in l.items():
    def _f():
        some_stuff()
    globals()[keys] = _f
    del _f

one()
two()
three()
```

output:

> some stuff
>
> some stuff
>
> some stuff

Comment: @deceze user wants to create function from dictionary keys

Comment: @deceze it's not your job. :)