# Dynamically decorate a function inside a class in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, metaprogramming

This is an extension of [Dynamic/runtime method creation (code generation) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533382/dynamic-runtime-method-creation-code-generation-in-python/534597#534597)

@John Montgommery properly answered @Eli Bendersky 's question that you can dynamically create a class with function using this logic:

```
class Dynamo(object):
    pass

def add_dynamo(cls,i):
    def innerdynamo(self):
        print "in dynamo %d" % i
    innerdynamo.__doc__ = "docstring for dynamo%d" % i
    innerdynamo.__name__ = "dynamo%d" % i
    setattr(cls,innerdynamo.__name__,innerdynamo)

for i in range(2):
    add_dynamo(Dynamo, i)

d=Dynamo()
d.dynamo0()
d.dynamo1()
```

My question is: How do you decorate the resulting functions within that class with a decorator that needs a parameter?

eg:
Static function definition:

```
class MyTaskSequence(TaskSequence):
    @seq_task(1)
    def sequence1(self):
        self.client.get("/devops/")

    @seq_task(2)
    def sequence2(self):
        self.client.get("/blog/")
```

What I tried:

```
class MyTaskSequence(TaskSequence):
    pass


def add_sequence(cls, order, path):
    def sequence(self):
        self.client.get(path)
    sequence.__name__ = "sequence%d" % order
    setattr(cls, sequence.__name__, seq_task(order)(sequence))

add_sequence(MyTaskSequence, 1, "/devops/")
add_sequence(MyTaskSequence, 2, "/blog/")
```

Comment: What is your problem with the code you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly apply the decorator when creating the method:

```
def add_sequence(cls, order, path):
    @seq_task(order)
    def sequence(self):
        self.client.get(path)
    sequence.__name__ = "sequence%d" % order
    setattr(cls, sequence.__name__, sequence)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I've printed the "order" value within that decorator function and it properly "fetched" the value.

Comment: Do you happen to also know the answer to a follow-up of this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247910/ensure-that-a-function-created-dynamically-inside-a-class-can-also-be-used-as-a ?