# Running a for loop to create functions with exec, inside a class, inside a function

Tags: python

I know it sounds complicated and it may not be possible, but I thought I'd try anyway.

So I'm doing some web scraping with Selenium, and any time that I want to run some jQuery on a page, instead of having

```
driver.execute_script("$('button').parent().click()")
```

I want to tidy up my code and just have

```
j('button').parent().click()
```

I'm attempting to accomplish this by having a class `j` and then when you have a function like `parent` it just returns another instance of that class.

In these examples I just have it printing the string that will get executed so that it can be tested more easily. And the way I have it the class exists inside a function.

So in this example everything works fine when all the class functions are defined normally, but if you uncomment the `for` loop section and define the `.parent()` function with `exec` then you get the error `NameError: name 'j' is not defined`:

```
def browser():

    class j:

        def __init__(self, str):
            if str[0] == '$':
                self.jq = str
            else:
                self.jq = f"$('{str}')"

        def click(self):
            output = f"{self.jq}.click()"
            print(output)
            return j(output)

        def parent(self):
            return j(f'{self.jq}.parent()')

        # functions = 'parent, next, prev'
        # for fn in functions.split(', '):
        #     exec(
        #         f"def {fn} (self):\n" +
        #         f"    return j(f'{{self.jq}}.{fn}()')"
        #     )

    j('button').parent().click()

browser()
```

However, if you move everything outside of the `browser` function and run everything then there's no error that way also, and that's if you define the functions either way.

I also tried doing `exec(code, globals())` but that just gave me a different error message instead: `AttributeError: 'j' object has no attribute 'parent'`

Is there some way to define functions with `exec` in this way and do what I'm try to do?

Edit:
This is the entire error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rob\Desktop\site\mysite\py\z.py", line 30, in <module>
    browser()
  File "C:\Users\Rob\Desktop\site\mysite\py\z.py", line 28, in browser
    j('button').parent().click()
  File "<string>", line 2, in parent
NameError: name 'j' is not defined
```

Comment: [Dynamic/runtime method creation (code generation) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533382/dynamic-runtime-method-creation-code-generation-in-python)

Comment: Instead of dynamically generating those methods, just implement `__getattr__` or similar magic methods and handle the call to undefined methods that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Furas's second answer got me most of the way there so he deserves the upvotes. But I managed to improve on it and get it to do everything I was looking for.

So here is my version that can take arguments and checks type and puts quotes around strings but not numbers.

```
def browser():

    class j:

        def __init__(self, str):
            self.jq = f"$('{str}')"

        def click(self):
            self.jq += ".click()"
            print(self.jq)
            return self

        @classmethod
        def quotes(cls, arg):
            q = "'" * (type(arg) == str and len(arg) > 0)
            output = f'{q}{arg}{q}'
            return output

        @classmethod
        def add_function(cls, name):
            def func(cls, arg=''):
                cls.jq += f'.{name}({j.quotes(arg)})'
                return cls
            func.__name__ = name
            setattr(j, name, func)

    j_functions = 'closest, eq, find, next, parent, parents, prev'
    for fn in j_functions.split(', '):
        j.add_function(fn)

    j('button').eq(0).next('br').prev().click()

browser()


>> $('button').eq(0).next('br').prev().click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `setattr` and examples from 
[Dynamic/runtime method creation (code generation) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533382/dynamic-runtime-method-creation-code-generation-in-python) I made:

```
def browser():

    class j:

        def __init__(self, str):
            if str[0] == '$':
                self.jq = str
            else:
                self.jq = f"$('{str}')"

        def click(self):
            output = f"{self.jq}.click()"
            print('click:', output)
            return j(output)

        def fun(self, name):
            return j(f'{self.jq}.{name}()')

        def fun2(self, name):
            self.jq += f'.{name}()'
            return self

    # - after class -

    functions = 'parent, next, prev'
    for fn in functions.split(', '):
         #setattr(j, fn, lambda cls, fun=fn: j(f'{cls.jq}.{fun}()'))
         #setattr(j, fn, lambda cls, fun=fn: j.fun(cls, fun))
         setattr(j, fn, lambda cls, fun=fn: cls.fun(fun))

    print('test:', j('button').parent().next().click().fun2('a').fun('b').jq)

browser()
```

But it is not ideal - it creates something like `next = fun("next")` and it may run it as `next("x")` and add `.x()` instead of `.next()`

---

I tested also `return self` instead of creating new instance - and it also works.

Beacuse `lambda` is use in `for`-loop so it needs `fun=fn` to correctly get value from `fn` . Without this it will take value from `fn` when it will be executed and then all function get the same value from `fn` - last value assigned to `fn` in loop.

---

**EDIT:** Instead of running directly `setattr` with `lambda` I run function which runs `setattr` and use inner function instead of `lambda` - this way it can create function without second argument so now `.next("x")` raise error.

```
def browser():

    class j:

        def __init__(self, str):
            if str[0] == '$':
                self.jq = str
            else:
                self.jq = f"$('{str}')"

        def click(self):
            output = f"{self.jq}.click()"
            print('click:', output)
            return j(output)

        def fun(self, name):
            return j(f'{self.jq}.{name}()')

        def fun2(self, name):
            self.jq += f'.{name}()'
            return self

        @classmethod
        def add_function(cls, name):
            def func(cls):
                cls.jq += f'.{name}()'
                return cls
            func.__name__ = name
            setattr(j, name, func)

    # - after class -

    functions = 'parent, next, prev'
    for fn in functions.split(', '):
         #setattr(j, fn, lambda cls, fun=fn: j(f'{cls.jq}.{fun}()'))
         #setattr(j, fn, lambda cls, fun=fn: j.fun(cls, fun))
         #setattr(j, fn, lambda cls, fun=fn: cls.fun(fun))
         #setattr(j, fn, lambda cls: cls.fun(x))
         j.add_function(fn)

    item = j('button').parent().next().click().fun2('a').fun('b')
    print('test:', item.jq)

    j.add_function('other')

    item = item.other()
    print('test:', item.jq)

    item = j('input').other().click()
    print('test:', item.jq)

    print('name:', j.next.__name__) # gives `next`, without `func.__name__ = name` it gives `func`

browser()
```

---

I tested also `__getattr__`

```
def browser():

    class j:


        def __init__(self, str):
            if str[0] == '$':
                self.jq = str
            else:
                self.jq = f"$('{str}')"

        def click(self):
            return self.fun('click')
            #self.jq += f".click()"
            #return self

        def fun(self, name):
            self.jq += f'.{name}()'
            return self

        functions = ['parent', 'next', 'prev']

        #def __getattr__(self, name):
        #    '''acceptes every name'''
        #    return lambda: self.fun(name) # I use `lambda` because it needs function to use `()`

        #def __getattr__(self, name):
        #    '''___name__ doesn't change its name in error message and it shows `<lambda>`'''
        #    a = lambda: self.fun(name)
        #    a.__name__ = name
        #    return a

        def __getattr__(self, name):
            '''acceptes only name from list `functions`'''
            if name in self.functions:
                return lambda: self.fun(name) # I use `lambda` because it needs function to use `()`
            else:
                raise AttributeError(f"'j' object has no attribute '{name}'")

        #def __getattr__(self, name):
        #    '''test running without `fun()`'''
        #    self.jq += f'.{name}()'
        #    return lambda:self # I use `lambda` because it needs function to use `()`


    # - after class -

    item = j('button').parent().next().click().fun('a').fun('b')
    print('test:', item.jq)

    j.functions.append('other')
    item = item.other()
    print('test:', item.jq)

    item = j('input').other().click()
    print('test:', item.jq)

    #print('name:', j.next.__name__) # doesn't work

    print(j('a').tests().jq) 

browser()
```

Comment: I created new code which does't run directly `setattr` with `lambda` but it runs other function which runs `setattr` and it doesn't need `lambda`

Comment: Thanks for the improvements. This got me most of the way there. I've worked on your answer and managed to get to pretty much 100% of what I was trying for. Do you mind if I post an updated version of this answer?

Comment: I tested also magic function `__getattr__` and I put it in answer.