# Generating functions inside loop with lambda expression in python

Tags: python, lambda, scope

If I make two lists of functions:

```
def makeFun(i):
    return lambda: i

a = [makeFun(i) for i in range(10)]
b = [lambda: i for i in range(10)]
```

why do lists `a` and `b` not behave in the save way?

For example:

```
>>> a[2]()
2
>>> b[2]()
9
```

Comment: See also [python - How do lexical closures work? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233673/how-do-lexical-closures-work)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Technically, the lambda expression is *closed* over the `i` that's visible in the global scope, which is last set to 9. It's the *same* `i` being referred to in all 10 lambdas. For example,

```
i = 13
print b[3]()
```

In the `makeFun` function, the lambda closes on the `i` that's defined when the function is invoked. Those are ten *different* `i`s.

Comment: Ok, now this makes sense for me. Thanks!

Comment: As of Python 3, list comprehensions have their own scope now. So changing it's value wouldn't change what print(b[3]()) would output. More details about the list comprehension behavior can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198906/list-comprehension-rebinds-names-even-after-scope-of-comprehension-is-this-righ)

Answer (score 24):

As others have stated, scoping is the problem. Note that you can solve this by adding an extra argument to the lambda expression and assigning it a default value:

```
>> def makeFun(i): return lambda: i
... 
>>> a = [makeFun(i) for i in range(10)]
>>> b = [lambda: i for i in range(10)]
>>> c = [lambda i=i: i for i in range(10)]  # <-- Observe the use of i=i
>>> a[2](), b[2](), c[2]()
(2, 9, 2)
```

The result is that `i` is now explicitly placed in a scope confined to the `lambda` expression.

Answer (score 7):

One set of functions (a) operates on the argument passed and the other (b) operates on a global variable which is then set to 9. Check the disassembly:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(a[2])
  1           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (i)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(b[2])
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (i)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

To add some clarity (at least in my mind)

```
def makeFun(i): return lambda: i
a = [makeFun(i) for i in range(10)]
b = [lambda: i for i in range(10)]
```

a uses makeFun(i) which is a function with an argument.

b uses lambda: i which is a function **without** arguments. The i it uses is very different from the previous

To make a and b equal we can make both functions to use no arguments:

```
def makeFun(): return lambda: i
a = [makeFun() for i in range(10)]
b = [lambda: i for i in range(10)]
```

Now both functions use the global i

```
>>> a[2]()
9
>>> b[2]()
9
>>> i=13
>>> a[2]()
13
>>> b[2]()
13
```

Or (more useful) make both use one argument:

```
def makeFun(x): return lambda: x
a = [makeFun(i) for i in range(10)]
b = [lambda x=i: x for i in range(10)]
```

I deliberately changed i with x where the variable is local.
Now:

```
>>> a[2]()
2
>>> b[2]()
2
```

Success !

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas in python share the variable scope they're created in. In your first case, the scope of the lambda is makeFun's. In your second case, it's the global `i`, which is 9 because it's a leftover from the loop.

That's what I understand of it anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Nice catch.  The lambda in the list comprehension is seeing the same local `i` every time.

You can rewrite it as:

```
a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append(makefun(i))

b = []
for i in range(10):
    b.append(lambda: i)
```

with the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. In your example, `b[2]()` also returns 9.

Comment: I'm saying it's equivalent to the list comprehensions; not that a and b and the same. 

I figured the spelled-out `for` loops would make it easier to see where `i` comes from.