# List or generator of lambda funcs do not return the same result in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

When I do:

```
def create_funcs():
    return (lambda: i for i in range(5))

for f in create_funcs():
    print(f())
```

I get the expected:

```
1
2
3
4
```

But when I do:

```
def create_funcs():
    return [lambda: i for i in range(5)]

for f in create_funcs():
    print(f())
```

I get a weird:

```
4
4
4
4
```

Can anyone explain why ?

Comment: @BrenBarn: Sorry I don't understand how the answer of the other question relates to mine.

Comment: Look in particular at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575698/python-list-comprehension-overriding-value/4575866#4575866).

Comment: @BrenBarn: OK but I am on Python3.5, so why would it leak ?

Comment: I realized your question is slightly different from that one because your comprehensions include a lambda.  I've given an answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `lambda` function captures a variable `i` from the surrounding scope.  As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575698/python-list-comprehension-overriding-value/) that scope is the scope of the comprehension.

Your loop iterates through the items from the generator one at a time and calls each one before advancing the generator.  When you get the first function, the generator is suspended in a state where `i` is 0, so that is the value that the function sees.  When you advance the generator, it sets `i` to 1, and you get a function that grabs that value.  The generator "waits" to change `i` until you advance to the next function.

In the list comprehension, you get all the functions at once.  But all are still referencing the same variable `i` inside the comprehension scope.  Since the list comprehension goes all the way to the end right away, `i` goes all the way to 4 before you get a chance to use any of the functions.

In both cases, your lambda is referencing a variable in the comprehension scope.  It's just that in the generator comprehension, this variable doesn't advance until after you have already called the previous function.  You can see similar behavior to the list-comprehension case if you store the first function, but don't call it until after you advance the generator again:

```
def create_funcs():
    return (lambda: i for i in range(5))

gen = create_funcs()
f1 = next(gen)
f2 = next(gen)
print(f1())
print(f2())
```

The output is

```
1
1
```

Since I advanced the generator, `i` is 1, so both `f1` and `f2` see that value when they are called.  You can see the same thing if you do `for f in list(create_funcs())`, forcing the generator to go all the way to the end as the list comprehension does.

Comment: I see. If I replace `lambda: i` with `lambda: int(i)` it works since I am not refering to i directly anymore. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin: Using `int(i)` shouldn't change anything.

Comment: `lambda: int(i)` should behave exactly the same way as your current code. If you want to work around the issue, use `lambda i=i: i`. That binds the value of `i` at the time the lambda is created to a default value in the lambda's own namespace.

Comment: Ooops ! I didn't realize I was on the generator function. Yes, it doesn't change anything since `i` is only evaluated when the function is called.

Comment: @Blckknght: That's interesting ! Using a default argument in the lambda stores the value in the function !! That's a creative use of default arguments... I cannot make my mind if I like it or not :)

Answer (score -1):

As BrenBarn alluded to, the variable `i` in the list comprehension is local to the scope of the comprehension. This will work if you use parenthesis:

```
def create_funcs():
    return (lambda: i for i in range(5))

for f in create_funcs():
    print(f())

0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: He already does that in the first example in his question.  His question is why the behavior is different in the two cases.