# access scope of variable in for loop

Tags: python

I have searched the SO before I post this question here and hopefully
this is not a duplicated one.

```
def print_me():
    a_list = range(1, 10)
    for idx, aa in enumerate(a_list):
        pass
    print(idx)

if __name__ == '__main__' : print_me()
```

Output is as follows:

> 8

I came from C++ world and could not figure out why `idx` is still in the scope when
the code is out side of for loop?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`for` loop doesn't create any scope. This is the reason.

In this particular code `idx` is a local variable of the `print_me` function.

**From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding):**

The following are blocks:

- a module
- a function body
- a class definition

**Update**

Generator expressions have their own scopes too.

[As of Python 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198906/python-list-comprehension-rebind-names-even-after-scope-of-comprehension-is-this/4199355#4199355) list comprehensions also have their own scopes.

Comment: In fact, only very few language constructs create scopes. There's only module scope, class scope and function scope, and that's about it.

Comment: List comprehensions also have their own scopes. Well, any comprehension or generator expression.

Comment: Anyone knows *why* Python doesn't create a scope for `for` / `while` loops? Is there any benefit to having those variables present later? (The disadvantage is clearly namespace pollution, hence more bugs.)