# What are list comprehension scoping rules within a Python class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-3.5

In the following code, the `mc` assigment works fine in Python 2 and 3.

The `cc` assignment, which uses the same list comprehension within a class, works in Python 2 but fails with Python 3.

What explains this behavior?

```
ml1 = "a b c".split()
ml2 = "1 2 3".split()
mc = [ i1 + i2 for i1 in ml1 for i2 in ml2 ]

class Foo(object):
    cl1 = ml1
    cl2 = ml2

    cc1 = [ i1 for i1 in cl1 ]
    cc2 = [ i2 for i2 in cl2 ]
    cc = [ i1 + i2 for i1 in cl1 for i2 in cl2 ]


print("mc = ", mc)
foo = Foo()
print("cc = ", foo.cc)
```

I get this:

```
(default-3.5) snafu$ python2 /tmp/z.py 
('mc = ', ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'])
('cc = ', ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'])

(default-3.5) snafu$ python3 /tmp/z.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/z.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Foo(object):
  File "/tmp/z.py", line 11, in Foo
    cc = [ i1 + i2 for i1 in cl1 for i2 in cl2 ]
  File "/tmp/z.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
    cc = [ i1 + i2 for i1 in cl1 for i2 in cl2 ]
NameError: name 'cl2' is not defined
```

Why is the class variable `cl2` not defined? Note that the `cc2` assignment  works fine, as does `cc1`. Swapping `cl1` and `cl2` in the comprehension shows that the second loop is the one that triggers the exception, not `cl2` per se.)

Versions:

```
(default-3.5) snafu$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.11+
(default-3.5) snafu$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.1+
```

Comment: This is related to class variables vs instance variables, not comprehension scoping.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Actually, it really is about variable scope in class-level comprehensions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136955/python3-nested-list-comprehension-scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3, list comprehensions have their own scope, which follows the same rules as a function scope. You know how the methods of a class don't automatically look inside the class scope for variable lookup?

```
class Example:
    var = 1
    def this_fails(self):
        print(var)
Example().this_fails()  # NameError
```

The same applies to any function scope nested inside a class scope, *including the scope of the list comprehension*. The lookup of `cl2` inside the list comprehension bypasses the class scope and goes straight to the globals. It effectively works like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    ...
    def make_cc(outer_iterable):
        result = []
        for i1 in outer_iterable:
            for i2 in cl2:  # This fails
                result.append(i1 + i2)
        return result
    cc = make_cc(cl1)  # cl1 is evaluated outside the comprehension scope, for reasons
```

Note that the `cl1` lookup works fine, because that happens at class scope, outside the comprehension, despite being syntactically nested inside the comprehension. [They made that decision](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#early-binding-versus-late-binding) back when Python introduced genexps, because it catches a few common genexp errors earlier. It's also why the `cc1` and `cc2` list comprehensions work; their only use of class-level variables is in their outer (only) `for` iterable.

Using comprehensions and generator expressions inside a class statement is a mess. It shouldn't be, but it is. Stick to regular loops, or run the comprehensions outside the class statement so the semantics are more obvious.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, however, it doesn't explain (to me) why `cc1 = [ i1 for i1 in cl1 ]` works but `cc = [ i1 + i2 for i1 in cl1 for i2 in cl2 ]` doesn't. Won't the scoping rules be the same?

Comment: @mhawke: The iterable of the first `for` gets evaluated outside the comprehension scope and passed to the anonymous function as an argument, most likely for symmetry with generator expressions, which work that way because it catches a few common errors earlier.

Comment: "Using comprehensions and generator expressions inside a class statement is a mess." I agree: The successful `cc1` and `cc2` assignments and failed `cc` assignment seem uncharacteristically surprising and unintuitive.

Comment: Consider `itertools.product`. The above comprehension becomes `cc = [ i1 + i2 for i1, i2 in itertools.product(cl1, cl2) ]`, which *does* work within classes for the reasons given in the above answer.