# Irregularity in Python class variable assignment

Tags: python, initialization

I'm trying to create a class which has multiple class-level variables, some of which have calculated values which reference previously declared class-level variables. However, I'm having difficulty referencing the variables at certain points.

My first attempt:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from decimal import Decimal
import math

class Foo(object):
    NUM_BUCKETS = 10
    BUCKET_SIZE = Decimal(1.0 / NUM_BUCKETS)
    BUCKET_LABELS = tuple("BUCKET_{}".format(int(BUCKET_SIZE * i * 100)) for i in xrange(1, NUM_BUCKETS + 1))

print Foo.BUCKET_LABELS
```

Result:

```
> python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Foo(object):
  File "test.py", line 8, in Foo
    BUCKET_LABELS = tuple("BUCKET_{}".format(int(BUCKET_SIZE * i * 100)) for i in xrange(1, NUM_BUCKETS + 1))
  File "test.py", line 8, in <genexpr>
    BUCKET_LABELS = tuple("BUCKET_{}".format(int(BUCKET_SIZE * i * 100)) for i in xrange(1, NUM_BUCKETS + 1))
NameError: global name 'BUCKET_SIZE' is not defined
```

Trying to access the class variable via the class name doesn't work either:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from decimal import Decimal
import math

class Foo(object):
    NUM_BUCKETS = 10
    BUCKET_SIZE = Decimal(1.0 / NUM_BUCKETS)
    BUCKET_LABELS = tuple("BUCKET_{}".format(int(Foo.BUCKET_SIZE * i * 100)) for i in xrange(1, NUM_BUCKETS + 1))

print Foo.BUCKET_LABELS
```

Result:

```
> python test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Foo(object):
  File "test2.py", line 8, in Foo
    BUCKET_LABELS = tuple("BUCKET_{}".format(int(Foo.BUCKET_SIZE * i * 100)) for i in xrange(1, NUM_BUCKETS + 1))
  File "test2.py", line 8, in <genexpr>
    BUCKET_LABELS = tuple("BUCKET_{}".format(int(Foo.BUCKET_SIZE * i * 100)) for i in xrange(1, NUM_BUCKETS + 1))
NameError: global name 'Foo' is not defined
```

Replacing the reference to BUCKET_SIZE with a hardcoded value fixes the problem; even though there's another class-level variable reference in the same line, it works just fine:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from decimal import Decimal
import math

class Foo(object):
    NUM_BUCKETS = 10
    BUCKET_SIZE = Decimal(1.0 / NUM_BUCKETS)
    BUCKET_LABELS = tuple("BUCKET_{}".format(int(Decimal(0.1) * i * 100)) for i in xrange(1, NUM_BUCKETS + 1))

print Foo.BUCKET_LABELS
```

Result:

```
> python test3.py
('BUCKET_10', 'BUCKET_20', 'BUCKET_30', 'BUCKET_40', 'BUCKET_50', 'BUCKET_60', 'BUCKET_70', 'BUCKET_80', 'BUCKET_90', 'BUCKET_100')
```

Does anybody know the correct way of referencing BUCKET_SIZE in that spot? Is this a bug in Python itself? (I'm running Python 2.7.5, BTW.)

Comment: This looks like a problem with generator expression scope, because the error went away when I changed it to a list comprehension.

Comment: Also NUM_BUCKETS works good in the generator, issue just in the part with BUCKET_SIZE

Comment: Essentially a dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136955/python3-nested-list-comprehension-scope), except that question is on Python 3 and using a list comprehension. I don't see any good dupe candidates using genexps.

Comment: @Laurent:  I stand corrected, comment deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a solution among others, by simply editing this one line (notice the brackets):

```
BUCKET_LABELS = tuple(["BUCKET_{}".format(int(BUCKET_SIZE * i * 100)) for i in xrange(1, NUM_BUCKETS + 1)])
```

---

Now, if you are curious as to *why* it works like that in Python, and why it is not a bug... Well, it is not an easy one :-) :

`[i*2 for i in xrange(3)]` is a *list comprehension*. It generates an actual list,  which can be used like this for example:

```
>>> a = [i*2 for i in xrange(3)]
>>> a
[0, 2, 4]
```

`(i*2 for i in xrange(3))` is a *generator expression*. It works in a rather similar way, but not exactly, since it does not generate a list or a tuple, but rather, a generator:

```
>>> a = (i*2 for i in xrange(3))
>>> a
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x02CEE058>
>>> a.next()
0
>>> a.next()
2
>>> a.next()
4
>>> a.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> a = (i*2 for i in xrange(3))
>>> tuple(a)
(0, 2, 4)
>>> tuple(a)
()
```

You can find more information here if you are curious: [generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

The tl;dr version is that a generator cannot be accessed directly (you must ask it to generate its content, using `next()` for example), and that each value can only be generated once (and then the generator moves on to the next one, hence the `next()` function name).

So, coming back at your problem. In the expression below, you actually ask to generate a tuple with a generator expression, which is fine in itself. Nonetheless, you do it by using Foo class variables, which in the case of a generator, can be problematic.

```
BUCKET_LABELS = tuple("BUCKET_{}".format(int(BUCKET_SIZE * i * 100)) for i in xrange(1, NUM_BUCKETS + 1))
```

In particular, the generator does not actually know about `Foo.BUCKET_SIZE` variable at all once you ask him to generate a tuple out of it (a generator works within in its scope, contrary to a list). This is why you get this error.

So, one solution is simply to rather use a list comprehension (which is more easy to handle/intuitive anyway).

PS: the `Decimal()` function probably does not do what you think it does:

```
>>> NUM_BUCKETS = 10
>>> print Decimal(1.0 / NUM_BUCKETS)
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
>>> print round(1.0 / NUM_BUCKETS, 2)
0.1
```

PPS: the reason why you do not get an error with the `xrange(1, NUM_BUCKETS + 1)` part, if you are curious about it, is because it is evaluated *before* the generator is built, so, that class variable is actually replaced by its value for the generator... which does not complain about it.

Comment: Your proposed fix breaks on Python 3. It's generally best to just not use genexps or comprehensions at all inside a class statement.

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed, I tested all of that in Python 2.7.

Comment: Thanks! That works. (Also, I know the decimal division thing is wrong. The latest version changes it to `Decimal(1) / NUM_BUCKETS`, which works as expected.)