# How to access dictionary value from class variable while creating a new dictionary

Tags: python, class, dictionary

This seems like a really weird scoping issue:

First I'll show what works:

```
class A():
   x = 1
   y = x

class B():
   x = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}
   y = {z : 1 for z in x}
```

Does not work:

```
class C():
   x = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}
   y = {z : max(x) for z in x}    #  max could be replaced with any function
```

Leading to:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

And I know it refers to the "inner" (value) in the dictionary comprehension.

This probably means that somehow in the list comprehension the class scope is not available.

How come, and how can we work around this (without using it as an instance variable, i.e. using __init__)?

Comment: Or even not a function - `y = {z: x for z in x}` won't work either. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/22692227/3001761

Comment: I was aware that not using a function does not work, but I assume some people start complaining that it wouldnt make sense... Though nicely found!

Comment: The class scope is surely avaiable to a list-comprhension in Python 2, but not to other comprehensions. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding