# Can't call parent's method in list comprehension in child's initializer, but explicit loop works

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

The `child` class inherits from the `parent` class. Inside the constructor of `child` I am initializing a `list`-type member variable`xs`  by repeatedly calling the member function `foo()` defined in `parent`. It turns out that if I initialize `xs` by explicitly looping and appending each value returned by `foo()`, everything works fine.

However, if I try to do the same thing within a list comprehension, I get a strange error thrown at me. Why does this error occur? What is the difference between a list comprehension in this case, and the explicit loop?

The MWE for the code that does work:

```
class parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

    def foo(self, a):
        return self.x


class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.xs = []
        for i in range(9):
            self.xs.append(super().foo(i))    

mychild = child()
```

The definition of `child` but with the list comprehension:

```
class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.xs = [super().foo(i) for i in range(9)]
```

The error in question:

```
% python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    mychild = child()
  File "test.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.xs = [super().foo(i) for i in range(9)]
  File "test.py", line 17, in <listcomp>
    self.xs = [super().foo(i) for i in range(9)]
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
zsh: exit 1     python test.py
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List comprehensions are actually run in a separate scope (see e.g. [Why is one class variable not defined in list comprehension but another is?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22692227/3001761)), so the implicit form of `super` with no arguments won't work inside the list comprehension.

You have two options, assuming that you don't want to go back to the standard `for` loop:

1. Use the explicit form of `super`, passing the class and instance arguments: `super(child, self).foo(i)`; or
2. As you've inherited `foo` from `parent`, just call it on the instance: `self.foo(i)`.