# NameError using eval inside dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm trying to code a dictionary inside my class:

```
data = {element:eval("self.%s" %element) for element in key}
```

and I've got this error:

```
data = {element:eval("self.%s" %element) for element in key}
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

If I do:

```
 for element in key:
     data[element]=eval("self.%s" %element)
```

No error here.

How come?

Comment: List comprehensions, dict comprehensions, generator expressions, etc have their own scope. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162886/cant-call-parents-method-in-list-comprehension-in-childs-intializer-but-expl) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692227/why-is-one-class-variable-not-defined-in-list-comprehension-but-another-is)

Comment: I do not think the the duplicate question completely answers this case . This is a bit related to `eval()` as well.

Comment: Why are you doing this (`eval`)?

Comment: Are you aware of `getattr(self, element)`, which would be easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL:DR** Summary -

As stated correctly by @CoryKramer , partially this is because dictionary comprehension/list comprehension/generator expressions/nested funcions all are evaluated in their own scope. But other half of the reason for this issue is because of the use of `eval()` , which executes its expressions in the environment in which it is called , but it does not have access to enclosing namespaces.

Alternatively ,I believe you should not use `eval()` ([its pretty dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)) . For getting attributes from `self` , you should use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function -

```
data = {element:getattr(self,element) for element in key}
```

---

My findings about the issue for those who are interested -

Partially this is because dictionary comprehension/list comprehension/generator expressions/nested funcions all are evaluated in their own scope. But other half of the reason for this issue is because of the use of `eval()` .

As given in the documentation for [`eval()` -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

> `eval(expression[, globals[, locals]])`
>
> **If both dictionaries are omitted, the expression is executed in the environment where eval() is called.** The return value is the result of the evaluated expression. Syntax errors are reported as exceptions.

(Emphasis mine)

Normally inside a class , when you use dictionary comprehension you can use `self` and etc in that dictionary comprehension. Example -

```
>>> class CA:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.a = "Hello"
...             print({k:self.a for k in range(2)})
...
>>> CA()
{0: 'Hello', 1: 'Hello'}
<__main__.CA object at 0x008B22D0>
```

As you can see it was possible to access `self.a` within the dictionary comprehension. So now lets check what is the `locals()` (local namespace) for the dictionary comprehension -

```
... #same as above, just change the print function call.
print({k:locals() if k < 2 else self.a for k in range(2)})
```

Result -

```
{0: {'.0': <range_iterator object at 0x02373998>, 'self': <__main__.CA object at 0x008B22D0>, 'k': 1}, 
1: {'.0': <range_iterator object at 0x02373998>, 'self': <__main__.CA object at 0x008B22D0>, 'k': 1}}
```

As can be seen `'self'` is accessible inside the dictionary comprehension (as its a [*free variable*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) , and this only occured because I used `self.a` directly inside the dictionary comprehension , if I did not add that it wouldn't be a free variable there. Lets explain *free variables* a bit -

> If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block. If a name is bound at the module level, it is a global variable. (The variables of the module code block are local and global.) If a variable is used in a code block but not defined there, it is a *free variable*.

But when you use `eval()` to execute the expression, Python does not know about any names (beforehand, before executing the expression) that are used inside the `eval()` , hence it cannot bind the `self` as a free variable to the dicitonary comprehension. Example of print of `locals()` , when using `eval` to get `self.a` -

```
...
print({k:locals() if k < 2 else eval('self.a') for k in range(2)})
```

Result -

```
{0: {'.0': <range_iterator object at 0x023739B0>, 'k': 1}, 1: {'.0': <range_iterator object at 0x023739B0>, 'k': 1}}
```

Hence, when the expression is evaluated inside the eval it does not have the `self` variable defined in the environment it is executed. If you were to use `self` anywhere inside the dictionary comprehension , you would not end up with this error -

```
...
print({k:eval('self.a') if k < 2 else self for k in range(2)})
```

Result -

```
{0: 'Hello', 1: 'Hello'}
```

Because then the environment in which `eval` expression is getting executed has knows about the name binding `self` .

The exact same issue can be replicated using nested functions as well -

```
>>> def a():
...     localb = 10
...     def c():
...             print(locals())
...             print(eval('localb + 20'))
...     c()
...
>>> a()
{}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in a
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in c
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'localb' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `eval`. A better practice is to use `getattr`:

```
data = {element: getattr(self, element) for element in key}
```