# Python Name Error in dict comprehension when called inside a function

Tags: python

I have the following python2 code which gives a NameError:

```
def myfunc():


   myvar=50
    print myvar
    print eval('myvar')
    a = 'myvar'
    print { a:eval(a) }
    print { a:a for a in ['myvar'] }
    print { a:eval(a) for a in ['myvar'] }

myfunc()
```

and when I now execute this python code with python2, I get the following output:

```
50
50
{'myvar': 50}
{'myvar': 'myvar'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 13, in <module>
    myfunc()
  File "tester.py", line 11, in myfunc
    print { a:eval(a) for a in ['myvar'] }
  File "tester.py", line 11, in <dictcomp>
    print { a:eval(a) for a in ['myvar'] }
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'myvar' is not defined
```

Remark: This is running on a Mac...
When I run the code snippet OUTSIDE of a function it works as expected...

Comment: Your code runs fine in a script only because it's not inside a function. Move the code inside a function and call it in the main script body, and you should get the same error.

Comment: Thanks for that observation. I updated and simplified the question...

Comment: Same behaviour in Python 3.

Comment: If you `print(locals())` in the dict literal and in the dict comprehension, you see that `myvar` is present in the former, but not in the latter. It _is_ present in `locals()` if you directly use it, though, e.g. in `{a: myvar for a in ...}`, but not using `eval`. No idea why that is so, though. Conversely, when the code is not in a function, `myvar` is in `globals()`, which is the same in the dict comprehension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameError using eval inside dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763500/nameerror-using-eval-inside-dictionary-comprehension)

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by doing...

```
globs, locs = globals(), locals()
print { a:eval(a, globs, locs) for a in ['myvar'] }
```

An explanation can be found here: [eval fails in list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194934/eval-fails-in-list-comprehension)

Comment: Ah cool, so it is a not intuitive python issue! Interesting. Thanks for the answer...