# 4 Kinds of Python Namespace?

Tags: python, namespaces

I'm new to python and I got a question in an assignment that reads:

"Name the four types of namespaces in Python"

I'm coming from a java/C background and as I understand it namespaces have to do with scope?

I think that two of the types of namespaces have are global and local?

Comment: I'm guessing they mean local, global, module, and package...? Not to just give you the answer, but this should give you a start to continue your research.

Comment: Yes! I believe this is what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [An Introduction to Python by Guido van Rossum and Fred L. Drake, Jr.](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/PythonScopesandNameSpaces.html):

> A namespace is a mapping from names to objects.
>   Examples of namespaces are: the set of **built-in** names (functions such
>   as abs(), and built-in exception names); the **global** names in a module;
>   and the **local** names in a function invocation. In a sense the **set of
>   attributes of an object** also form a namespace. (my emphasis)

So there are four namespaces. In Python3 (but not Python2), list comprehensions also [have their own namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13913933/190597). In both Python2 and Python3 generator expressions have their own namespace, as you can see from the `NameError` raised by the following code:

```
In [175]: (1 for i in range(1))
Out[175]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x3a47d0f4>

In [176]: i
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

---

By the way, a scope related to, but not the same thing as a namespace. Whereas a namespace is a mapping between names and objects,

> A scope is a **textual region of a Python program** where a namespace is
>   directly accessible. "Directly accessible" here means that an
>   unqualified reference to a name attempts to find the name in the
>   namespace. (my emphasis)

Answer (score 0):

the innermost scope, which is searched first, contains the local names

the scopes of any enclosing functions, which are searched starting with the nearest enclosing scope, contains non-local, but also non-global names

the next-to-last scope contains the current module’s global names

the outermost scope (searched last) is the namespace containing built-in names