# Execution of class body

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#executing-the-class-body) says that the body of a declared class is executing roughly as `exec(body, globals(), namespace)`. Nevertheless, the following code raises a `NameError` (`global name 'r' is not defined`)

```
class Test:
    r = 3
    l = [i + r for i in range(r)]
```

while the following code succeeds with the expected result

```
class Test:
    r = 3
    l = []
    for i in range(r):
        l.append(i + r)
```

Furthermore, the following code also succeeds, with the expected result

```
code = """r = 3; l = [i + r for i in range(r)]"""
namespace = {}
exec(code, globals(), namespace)
```

What are the particularities of list comprehension making the first code raising an error? Is there a way to fix this problem but still keeping the list-comprehension style?

Comment: Did you check that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't find this answer before asking my question. Next time, I will search a bit more...