# Python: Why cannot access variable in class

Tags: python, python-3.x

The simple example:

```
class A():
   a = 1
   b = [a + i for i in range(3)]
```

It will raise

> NameError: name 'a' is not defined

However,

```
class A():
   a = 1
   b = a + 2
```

works.

What is the basic access rule in `Python3`?

Comment: This works in Python 2.7 :o

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`, not `TypeError`.

Comment: Working in python 2.7...

Comment: That isn't really the error that is caused.  It would be a `NameError` if it weren't for the fact that you defined a function called `a` that you didn't tell us about ;)

Comment: shoudn't any initialisation be done inside `__init__(self, ...)`?

Comment: @Raf `a` and `b` are [class attributes](https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition