# Why can't an inner class see declarations in an outer class?

Tags: python, class

Given the following ...

```
def foo(bar):
    return bar * 2

class FOO:
    BAR = 2
    a = foo(BAR)

    class FAZ:
        a = foo(BAR)
```

Why does python give a `NameError: name 'BAR' is not defined` error?  My expectation was that it would work given that `foo(BAR)` is allowed and classes are allowed to refer to things outside their scope.

```
$ python foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 6, in <module>
    class FOO:
  File "foo.py", line 10, in FOO
    class FAZ:
  File "foo.py", line 11, in FAZ
    a = foo(BAR)
NameError: name 'BAR' is not defined
```

Is there a technical reason for this limitation?  A design one?

Is there a workaround (aside from moving `BAR` outside the class)?  i.e.,

```
BAR = 2                                                                         

class FOO:                                                                      
    BAR = BAR                                                                   
    a = foo(BAR)                                                                

    class FAZ:                                                                  
      a = foo(BAR)
```

Edit:

Anyone following the link to the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition):

At first glance, the question is somewhat different -- works in python2, not in python3 and is about list comprehensions.  The accepted answer, however, seems to cover my question as well.

Comment: Because `BAR` must be referenced inside of `FOO`'s namespace, which *doesn't exist yet* since the class definition isn't finished executing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `FOO.BAR` isn't available until after the class is finished ... but I see your point. `BAR` isn't a variable exactly.

Comment: Yep, edited my question after I looked at it again. Honestly, nested classes are rare in most of the Python code I've seen (with some important exceptions, e.g. `django` does stuff with inner classes)

Comment: Would it make more sense to have `FAZ` as a subclass instead of a nested one?

Comment: Well, `BAR` is a variable that is in the class scope, which is sort of a special case in Python. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23471004/5014455)

Comment: @coldspeed Not if the nested class is `class Meta` in a Django model.  Which it is ....

Comment: Maybe the question should be instead why does `a = foo(BAR)` work!  But yeah, the scoping here is a little different than other languages.