# NameError for importing random and numpy.random, but nothing else

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, package

I've run into a strange case in my Python code, and I'm trying to figure out why this occurs.

```
rounds = 10
probability = 100
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
from numpy.random import uniform
for r in range(1, rounds):
    sample = {item: uniform() < probability for item in items}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following NameError:

```
File "sample.py", line 6, in <module>
  sample = {item: uniform() < probability for item in items}
File "sample.py", line 6, in <dictcomp>
  sample = {item: uniform() < probability for item in items}
NameError: name 'uniform' is not defined
```

This is very strange, since I am importing uniform directly before using it in the following line. I got the same error using the `random` module. I'm using other packages in my code (including `argparse` and `pickle`) but only the random number generation is giving me errors. I'm running Python 3 on a Windows machine. I also get the same error when I move the `import` statement inside the `for` loop.

```
rounds = 10
probability = 100
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for r in range(1, rounds):
    from numpy.random import uniform
    sample = {item: uniform() < probability for item in items}
```

What could be causing this error?

EDIT: I encountered another interesting phenomenon. The below code blocks are giving the same `NameError` for `uniform`.

```
from numpy.random import uniform
sample = {item: uniform() for item in [1,2,3]}
```

... and ...

```
from numpy.random import uniform
sample = [uniform() for item in [1,2,3]]
```

However, the following code does NOT give a `NameError` for `uniform`.

```
from numpy.random import uniform
sample = {1: uniform(), 2: uniform(), 3: uniform()}
```

There seems to be something in the way Python handles dictionary/list comprehensions that makes the first two code blocks illegal but the third one okay.

Comment: [mcve], please. Is this inside a class statement? There's clearly some context you're not showing us; your error message didn't come from the exact code you posted.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks, I'll post the minimal complete code to reproduce this error

Comment: That's strange. This kind of thing usually only happens with [class statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition), `exec`, and other constructs that create a scope that can't be used for closure variables.

Comment: Does running the posted code in isolation produce the error, or does it only happen as part of some larger program?

Comment: If you instead do import numpy, and then call the function using numpy.random.uniform() do you get the same error?

Comment: @user2357112 This code alone will produce this error. I'm running it as a `.py` script from the terminal.

Comment: @enumaris Yep, I get `NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined`

Comment: What happens if you try to call `uniform()` outside of a comprehension? If your file is nothing but `from numpy.random import uniform; uniform()`, do you get an error?

Comment: @user2357112, nope, there's no error

Comment: I edited the question. The for-loop is unnecessary. Furthermore, it looks like the error has to do with calling numpy's `uniform()` function inside of a list/dict-comprehension.

Comment: What happens if you put parentheses around `uniform() < probability` in your comprehension?

Comment: I gotta say, I'm having no luck reproducing your error with Python 3.6.4 on a Mac.

Comment: What are you using to execute Python? If you're running the script as `python sample.py`, what does `which python` produce? Something is really weird about how you're executing this code.

Comment: yep, I'm running it like `python sample.py` from a terminal. I'm running Windows, so `where.exe python` returns `C:\Python35\python.exe`. Interestingly, the failing code *does* work when I run Python interactively.

Comment: There's definitely something weird with my version of Python. Inside of another dict comprehension, I tried to access a variable `r` that I declared outside of the dictionary, and Python returned another `NameError` for `r`. At least for now, I'm going to step around this by using a simple `for` loop instead of comprehensions.

Comment: If this is Windows, I suggest uninstalling and reinstalling Python and seeing if the problem goes away. (Try Python 3.6.) Digging into the root cause could be interesting, but it's probably not the best use of your time.