# python3 class attributes scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class A(object):
    test = 'test'
    d = ['a', 'b']
    [i + test for i in d]
```

In python2.7, this code works, in python3.6, will report `NameError: name 'test' is not defined`.

I assume it's related to class attribute working scope change , but haven't found anythings in doc.

Comment: check out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition