# Initializing a static field in a Python class

Tags: python, class, static

I want to initialize a static field on declaration.

```
class Test:

    def _init_foo(): return 3

    foo = { _init_foo() for i in range(10)}
```

However, the interpreter is complaining

```
NameError: name '_init_foo' is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve? If you need class attribute `foo` to be same and shared for all instances, just write `foo = 3`. But it will not be static anyway.

Comment: Why this fails is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13913933/190597).

Comment: @Slam in the real case, foo must be a dictionary whose attributes are loaded from files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing class variables from a list comprehension in the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why this fails is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13913933/190597).

You could work around the problem by defining `foo` via a [class decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/). This works because by the time `add_foo` is called, the class has been defined and `_init_foo` in then accessible as `cls._init_foo`:

```
def add_foo(cls):
    cls.foo = { cls._init_foo() for i in range(10) }
    return cls

@add_foo
class Test:

    def _init_foo(): return 3


print(Test.foo)
# {3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before finding the class decorator option, I was initialising fields after the class declaration. I don't know which one I like less... :) I miss a static init block like in Java.

```
class Box:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        Box.count += 1  # static field usage

    @staticmethod
    def instance_count():
        return Box.count  # static field usage

Box.count = 0  # static field initialisation

b1 = Box(10)
b2 = Box(20)
print(Box.count)  # 2
```