# Python class variable assignment using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, class, dictionary, scoping

During a class definition, a class variable defined as a dictionary is used in the construction of a second dictionary class variable, a subset pared down from the first, like this:

```
class C(object):
    ALL_ITEMS = dict(a='A', b='B', c='C', d='D', e='E')
    SUBSET_X = {k: v for k, v in ALL_ITEMS.items() if k in ('a', 'b', 'd')}  # (this works)
    SUBSET_Y = {k: ALL_ITEMS[k] for k in ('a', 'b', 'd')}  # (this fails)
```

Pretty simple stuff, but the net effect of executing this code is quite surprising to me.  My first approach was the code on line 4, but I had to resort to the solution on line 3 instead.  There is something subtle about dictionary comprehension scoping rules that I'm clearly failing to grasp.

Specifically, the error raised in the failing case is:

```
File "goofy.py", line 4, in <dictcomp>
   SUBSET_Y = {k: ALL_ITEMS.get(k) for k in ('a', 'b', 'd')}
NameError: name 'ALL_ITEMS' is not defined
```

The nature of this error is baffling to me for a few different reasons:

1. The assignment to `SUBSET_Y` is a well-formed dictionary comprehension, and references a symbol which should be in-scope and accessible.
2. In the succeeding case (the assignment to `SUBSET_X`), which is also a dictionary comprehension, the symbol `ALL_ITEMS` is perfectly well-defined and accessible.  Thus, the fact that the raised exception is a `NameError` in the failing case seems manifestly wrong.  (Or misleading, at best.)
3. Why would the scoping rules differ for `items()` vs. `__getitem__` or `get()`?  (The same exception occurs replacing `ALL_ITEMS[k]` with `ALL_ITEMS.get(k)` in the failure case.)

(Even as a Python developer for over a decade, I've never run into this failure before, which either means I've been lucky or have lived a sheltered existence  :^)

The same failure occurs in various 3.6.x CPython versions as well as 2.7.x versions.

EDIT: No, this is not a duplicate of a previous question.  That pertained to list comprehensions, and even if one were to project the same explanation to dictionary comprehensions, it doesn't explain the difference between the two cases I cited.  And also, it is not a Python 3-only phenomenon.

Comment: I don't see ALL_KEYS anywhere in your code. Is the error referencing ALL_ITEMS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is one minor detail that explains why the first-version works but the second version fails. The reason the second version fails is the same reason that is given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition), namely, all comprehension constructs (in Python 3, in Python 2, list-comprehensions were implemented differently) create a function scope where all of the local name-bindings occur. However, names in a class scope are not accessible to functions defined inside the class scope. This is why you have to use either `self.MY_CLASS_VAR` or `MyClass.MY_CLASS_VAR` to access a class variable from a method.

The reason your first case does happen to work is subtle. According to the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)

> The comprehension consists of a single expression followed by at least
>   one for clause and zero or more for or if clauses. In this case, the
>   elements of the new container are those that would be produced by
>   considering each of the for or if clauses a block, nesting from left
>   to right, and evaluating the expression to produce an element each
>   time the innermost block is reached.
>
> However, **aside from the iterable expression in the leftmost for
>   clause, the comprehension is executed in a separate implicitly nested
>   scope.** This ensures that names assigned to in the target list don’t
>   “leak” into the enclosing scope.
>
> **The iterable expression in the leftmost for clause is evaluated
>   directly in the enclosing scope and then passed as an argument to the
>   implictly nested scope.**

So, in the first case, `ALL_ITEMS.items()` is in the left-most for-clause, so it is *evaluated directly in the enclosing scope*, in this case, the class scope, so it happily finds the `ALL_ITEMS` name.

Comment: So a few things, 1) of course, a fully-qualified name (e.g., `MyClass.MY_CLASS_VAR`) is not accessible in expressions assigning class variables _inside the class definition_, which I doubt you intended to suggest. Also, 2) the same workaround applies equally to Python 2 as in Python 3, so this doesn't appear to be a Python 3-ism as has been alluded to.  And finally, 3) yes, your explanation holds water vis-a-vis the spec, but man, is this ever a subtle trip-wire for the unsuspecting!

Comment: @trenchant 1) yes, MyClass won't be available during class definition time because it doesn't exist, and the class scope only exists during the definition. 2) for list-comprehensions, this would apply only in Python 3, because in Python 2 they had an implementation that didn't create a class scope but instead had a "leaky" scope. Dict and set comprehension never suffered from this, and in Python 3, list comprehension were re-implemented to work like set and dict comprehension-constructs already did 3) yeah it's subtle. I just avoid comprehension-constructs inside class scopes.