# How to resolve NameError when importing class with class variables that depend on each other

Tags: python, python-3.x

I create a class in a file. declare some class variable `A = 5` and another class variable `B = A+1`.
When importing that class from another file, I get a NameError: name 'A' is not defined.
Is there a way around this or can/should class variables not depend on other class variables the way I am trying to do that?

Note that this NameError only happens when I import form another file. If i were to define the classe and create an instance of that class in the same file, everything runs smoothly.

file: file1.py

```py
class foo:
    A = 5
    B = A+7
```

file: file2.py

```py
from file1 import foo
```

I then run:

```sh
python file2.py
```

and get

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined.
```

**EDIT :** The example above was too simplistic to reflect my actual problem.
I was actually trying to define a class as such:

```py
class foo:
    A = 5
    B = [i*A for A in range(3)]
```

The reasons why it doesn't work in Python 3 are to be found in the link in my answer.

Comment: @Dschoni That won't work because it's a class variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. My code snippet was too simplified to accurately reflect my real situation.
I was actually doing something like this:

```
class C:
    foo = 2
    bar = [i*foo for i in range(3)]
```

and then import that class from another file.
While this apparently works in python 2, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition), in Python 3:

> class scope and list comprehension do not mix.

So there you have it. This can actually be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Use the *qualified name* of the class variable:

In `this_module.py`:

```
class C:
    a = 0
    b = C.a + 1
```

...in some other file:

```
from this_module import C
```

Comment: @Mazata Shouldn't you accept your own answer in this circumstance and edit your question to reflect what you actually meant?

Comment: On second thought, yes you are right. I'll do that as soon as Stack Overflow lets me.