# Why does Python raise a NameError for conditional list comprehensions inside class attribute definitions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

This works:

```
class Foo:
    ATTR_1 = [1, 2]
    ATTR_2 = [i for i in ATTR_1]

    def __init__(self):
        print(Foo.ATTR_1, Foo.ATTR_2)
Foo()
```

It prints `[1, 2] [1, 2]`. However, adding a condition to the list comprehension in the third line causes Python to throw a `NameError`:

```
class Foo:
    ATTR_1 = [1, 2]
    ATTR_2 = [i for i in ATTR_1 if len(ATTR_1) > 0]

    def __init__(self):
        print(Foo.ATTR_1, Foo.ATTR_2)
Foo()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/tmp.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Foo:
  File "/path/to/tmp.py", line 3, in Foo
    ATTR_2 = [i for i in ATTR_1 if len(ATTR_1) > 0]
  File "/path/to/tmp.py", line 3, in <listcomp>
    ATTR_2 = [i for i in ATTR_1 if len(ATTR_1) > 0]
NameError: name 'ATTR_1' is not defined
```

Why is that and how can I work around it? I am using Python 3.6.4.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I think this is mostly addresssed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I am happy to see that there already is an excellent answer to this question and will flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: I was just writing up an answer that demonstrates the difference between the two uses of `ATTR_1`, so I'll comment instead. `ATTR_1` is a "local" name when used to get the iterator for the comprehension, but it is treated as a *global* in the anonymous function that implements the comprehension. See the output of `dis.dis('[i for i in ATTR_1 if len(ATTR_1) > 0]')` to see the difference.

Comment: @KilianBatzner You can define ATTR_1 as global outside of class: global ATTR_1 
ATTR_1= [1, 2]        
Foo()
print(ATTR_1)

class Foo:
    ATTR_2 = [i for i in ATTR_1 if(len(ATTR_1)>0)]

    def __init__(self):
        print(Foo.ATTR_2)