# Name Error when declaring a 2D array inside a class

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and I am trying to make a game that includes a 2D array as a board. I looked for how to declare a 2D array from StackOverflow previously but for some reason I get a `NameError` that cols is not defined. What am I am doing wrong?

```
class HelloWorld:
    rows = 5
    cols = 5
    arr = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
```

**Edit**: This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/MyName/Documents/Python Scripts/HelloWorld.py", line 1, in <module>
    class HelloWorld:
  File "c:/Users/MyName/Documents/Python Scripts/HelloWorld.py", line 4, in HelloWorld
    arr = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
  File "c:/Users/MyName/Documents/Python Scripts/HelloWorld.py", line 4, in <listcomp>
    arr = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
NameError: name 'cols' is not defined
```

Comment: can we see the exact error trace?

Comment: Note that variables declared at the scope of a class are class variables, not instance variables. They are shared between all instances, meaning you could not have instances with different game boards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing class variables from a list comprehension in the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition)