# NameError on dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, nameerror, dictionary-comprehension

I stumbled into a weird problem. I narrowed it down to the lines below just to focus on exactly what's happening so, please, don't mind the purposes of this code.

Code is:

```
dictionary = {
        'key': 'value'
}

class Test:

    a = {**dictionary}

    b = dictionary['key']

    c = {i: dictionary[i] for i in dictionary}
```

Runs without any problems.

If I change it to:

```
class Test:

    dictionary = {
        'key': 'value'
    }

    a = {**dictionary}

    b = dictionary['key']

    c = {i: dictionary[i] for i in dictionary}
```

I'll get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/PythonTest.py", line 2, in 
>       class Test:
>
> File "/home/PythonTest.py", line 12, in Test
>       c = {i: dictionary[i] for i in dictionary}
>
> File "/home/PythonTest.py", line 12, in 
>       c = {i: dictionary[i] for i in dictionary}
>
> NameError: name 'dictionary' is not defined

Why would the NameError be thrown only on the third assignment? When debugging, I see that assignments to variables a and b work just fine.

Comment: I assume `python3` :). Possible duplicate of [accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition)

Comment: try this [{i: y} for i,y in dictionary.items()]

Comment: It is duplicate as pointed out by @hansolo.