# what's happening in list_2 Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, class

```
 name = 'Guido'
 
 class MyClass:
     name = 'Raymond'
     list_1 = [name] * 3
     list_2 = [name for i in range(3)]

     @classmethod
     def hello(cls):
       return '{} says hello'.format(name)
```

**If i do this? it prints the following:**

```
>>> print(MyClass.hello())
Guido says hello
>>> print(MyClass.list_1) 
['Raymond', 'Raymond', 'Raymond']
>>> print(MyClass.list_2)
['Guido', 'Guido', 'Guido']
```

My question here is,

1. Why don't it prints 'Raymond' instead of 'Guido' on 3rd Output.
2. How to make it print as:

   > Raymond says hello

Comment: Please don't add line numbers, it makes your code a little more tedious to copy/paste

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition

Comment: thank you for mentioning, i've removed it!

Comment: DeepSpace, but i don't get still!

Answer (score 6):

Python provides two different kinds of *displays* (syntax that you could informally call a literal) for defining a list.

`list_1` is an "ordinary" list display, and uses the most recently bound value for `name`.

`list_2` is defined using a list comprehension, which is implemented using an anonymous function. Now `name` is a free variable in that function, and so it resolves to the value of `name` in the nearest enclosing scope. Because a `class` statement does not establish a new scope, that would be the global scope, *not* the temporary namespace established by the `class` statement.

Try to avoid using `class` attributes as "local" variables in your class definition.

In the class method, if you want `name` to be the class attribute, not the global variable, you need to be explicit:

```
@classmethod
def hello(cls):
    return '{} says hello'.format(cls.name)
```

Comment: Why does this work differently when I'm in a `function`? e.g. `def func(): name='Raymond'; l1 = [name] *3; l2 = [name for _ in range(3)]; return l1, l2`, when printing `l1` and `l2` in global, they are both "Raymond"s x3.

Comment: Functions define a new scope; a `class` statement does not.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, the inner nuances of scoping is not my strong suit.  Learned something new today.  Actually... now that I think of it, why *doesn't* a `class` statement define a new scope?

Comment: A function definition just saves the body to be executed every time the function is called. A class definition, though, executes the body of the class statement *immediately*, and is discarded after the statement completes. The values computed by any code and assigned to a name are used as class attributes, but the code itself is not retained.

Comment: It is respecting that rule. The `class` statement doesn't create a scope, though, so the class attribute simply doesn't apply. The immediate scope in `list_2` is the anonymous function's local scope, and since `name` isn't defined there, it looks in the closest enclosing scope, which is the global scope (because the `class` statement doesn't define a scope). A `class` statement does define a temporary *namespace*, which is a distinct concept from *scope*.

Comment: Thanks @chepner.  With your comment and the linked answer from Deepspace, I think I can understand it a bit better.  It'll probably take some time for me to digest the concept but thank you.