# Can't use class level variable

Tags: python

I have following code, that doesn't work:

```
class Node:
    n = 5
    options = [ i / (n-1) for i in range(n)]


print("Success")
```

Error I am getting is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ikkamens/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2019.2/scratches/counters.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Node:
  File "/Users/ikkamens/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2019.2/scratches/counters.py", line 3, in Node
    options = [ i / (n-1) for i in range(n)]
  File "/Users/ikkamens/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2019.2/scratches/counters.py", line 3, in <listcomp>
    options = [ i / (n-1) for i in range(n)]
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

However, the following changed version works:

```
class Node:
    n = 5
    options = [ i / 4 for i in range(n)]


print("Success")
```

Why can I use the class level variable in `range` expression, but not in `(n-1)`? Is this an interpreter bug or is there some rule to explain this behavior? I have tried it with 3.8 and 3.6 interpreters.

Comment: @DeepSpace Are you sure about that dupe target? Seems to be completely irrelevant. OP is missing proper scoping for `n`, which is interpreted as global. It has nothing to do with comprehension variable binding as far as I can tell. Of course, that scope does not exist before the class is instantiated, so this isn't possible AFAIK

Comment: @kabanus it is relevant. That code works on Python 2 where the list comprehension was  not implemented as a scope-creating anonymous function https://repl.it/repls/BrightLividBaitware

Comment: @DeepSpace Ah, I see the connection thanks. Hopefully the comment will make it clearer, especially if this is not an "upgraded from Python 2" question, but just a why this does not work question.

Comment: @DeepSpace Maybe to an expert the connection is clear, however I don't understand the cause after reading connected question / answer.

Comment: @RobertMcPythons-[a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition).  But neither this link or the dupe answers explains why the n in `(n-1)` is inaccessible but the n in `range(n)` is accessible.

Comment: Probably relevant to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition

Comment: @RobertMcPythons--error in my previous comment.  The section in "the related answer" link title *The (small) exception; or, why one part may still work* explains the error in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things here, as seen by the discussion under the OP.

**First**, in Python, there is no default object or class scope, such as the implicit `this` in C++. So inside a function, your scope is that function, and you do not have "free" name access to variables defined on the object on the class. That is the reason we have to pass `self` around - we need the environment containing our object (and class) explicitly. This means if we have

```
class A:
    n = 5
```

we can only access `n` in the class level definition, or by explicitly holding the environment:

```
class A:
    n = 5
    a = range(n) # legal, evaluated in the class definition, where 'A' is defined and 'n' is part of the statement.
    def f():
        x = self.n # legal. As long you do not override self.n same as next
        x = A.n # legal, this is the class variable scope
        x = n # Error - we do not have 'n' for free. Even worse, if 'n' is a global variable, we are using that.
```

**Second**, in Python 3, differently from Python 2 a list comprehension became scoped. No more leaking variables, and the body of the `class` statement isn't really a scope (rather the definition of a namespace), and so not the scope where the anonymous function that implements the comprehension is defined. So

```
class A:
    n = 5
    x = [n/a for a in range(n)]
```

might be seen as

```
class A:
    n = 5
    def _anonymous_function(param):
        return [n/a for a in range(param)]
    x = _anonymous_function(n)
```

This way, it might be clearer why `n` iss legal at one place, and not at the other. In the `range(n)`, similar to the first example in the second code snippet in the answer, we are still in the class namespace definition statement, and "see" `n`. On the other hand, in the comprehension body we are in a scoped (anonymous) environment, and do not see `n` as it not in the outer (global) scope, since `A` a namespace definition. This is the reason why it breaks here, as opposed to the other example. In Python 2 this would work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why its not work in this way but may be the interpreter think that 
  `(n-1)` 
in the list is belong to a local variable inside the list or part of the loop.Although,I am not sure.

You can do this way

```
class Node:
    global n
    n = 5
    options = [ i / (n-1) for i in range(n)]


print("Success")
```

Comment: Because the list comprehension is implemented using an anonymous function, the value of `n` isn't taken from the namespace in the `class` statement, but from the closest enclosing scope (which is the global scope here). Adding `global n` makes `n` resolve to that scope, not the `class` statement's namespace.

Comment: @chepner,I thought that would be the case,btw thanks for a clear explanation