# NameError referencing class variables in comprehension

Tags: python, class, variables, reference, nameerror

I get `NameError: name 'ID' is not defined` when trying to access the class variable in a dict comprehension e.g. in `class A`. When referencing without a comprehension it works fine (see `class B`). So my question is, why does it throw a NameError in class A but not in class B?

```
class A:
    ID = "This is class A."

    test = {str(i): ID for i in range(5)}

class B:
    ID = "This is class B."

    test = f"{ID}"
```

Comment: You question is not quite clear. can you explain what is `ID` ? And how is your `class B` working ?

Comment: ID is just a string which is used as an identifier of the class. I want to use the ID class variable in a dict comprehension in the same class but that throws a NameError. 
In the case of class B without a comprehension, it works. So my question is, why does it throw a NameError in class A but not in class B?

Comment: Can you post the full code ?  There might be something wrong in the way you are using it.  If you just copy 2 lines inside `class A` to python console it should works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition

Comment: @krismath Thanks, that definitely does!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Note on Resolution of Names in Python:

> Class definition blocks and arguments to `exec()` and `eval()` are special
>   in the context of name resolution. A class definition is an executable
>   statement that may use and define names. These references follow the
>   normal rules for name resolution with an exception that unbound local
>   variables are looked up in the global namespace. The namespace of the
>   class definition becomes the attribute dictionary of the class.
>   **The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class
>   block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods – this
>   includes comprehensions and generator expressions since they are
>   implemented using a function scope. This means that the following will
>   fail.**

You have declared a variable `ID` inside the class definition that makes it an `class` or `static` variable. So its **scope is limited the to class block**, and hence you can't access it inside the `comprehensions`.

you can read more about it at [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names)

Consider the examples,

**Example #1:**

```
class A:
    ID = "This is class A."
    print(ID)
```

Now when you execute `>>>A()` the output will be `This is class A` which is totally fine because the scope of variable `ID` is limited to class `A`

---

**Example #2:**

```
class B:
    L = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    print([i * 2 for i in L])
```

Now when you execute `>>>B()` the output will be `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]` which is totally fine because the scope of list `L` is limited to class B

---

**Example #3:**

```
class C:
   L = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
   print([L[i] * 2 for i in range(7)])
```

Now executing `>>>C()` will raise a `NameError` stating that name `L` is not defined.