# Method's decorator parameter cannot be a list comprehension based on class' static member

Tags: python, oop, decorator, pylint

Let's consider the following example:

```py
def dec(arg):
    def wrapper(m):
        def result(self):
            print(arg)
            m(self)
        return result
    return wrapper


class X:

    x = [7]

    @dec(x)
    def f(self):
        print('hello from f')

    @dec([i + 5 for i in x])
    def g(self):
        print('hello from g')


X().f()
X().g()
```

Code works fine under my `python3.6` installation, but pylint complains on `undefined-variable` `x` in decorator's parameter of `g` method. Why this happen? Is this code not a good idea to implement this way? If so - any alternatives?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in pylint, there's also [this issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1976).

Comment: I would just disable the warning: `@dec(...)  # pylint: disable=undefined-variable`

Comment: There's an old bug in Pylint "undefined-variable when using class attribute in listcomp in decorator" back from 2015 that looks like it was never fixed: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/511

Comment: @anjsimmo yes - that's exactly the stuff

Comment: Using list comprehensions in a class body tends to be a bad idea anyway due to a [completely different scope issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition), but that's not the issue you're hitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:** It's a bug in Pylint 2.4.4 (and older). [I've submitted a patch](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/3497), which has been merged into master, and will be included in the next release of Pylint.

**Details** (for the curious):

When Python parses the code into Abstract Syntax Tree [(AST)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar) nodes, decorator nodes (e.g `@dec...`) are attached to the `decorator_list` of the node for the function definition (e.g. `def g...`):

```
    stmt = FunctionDef(identifier name, arguments args,
                       stmt* body, expr* decorator_list, expr? returns,
                       string? type_comment)
```

Pylint had a special case for function arguments (`args`), but forgot to check the `decorator_list` and the `returns` annotation. This was causing Pylint to incorrectly treat the decorators as if they were inside the function, and thus in function scope rather than class scope.

**Workaround**:

As a static code checker, Pylint can only go so far. It currently has 500 open issues, so expect a few false positives. For now, you can follow [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)'s suggestion to disable the Pylint warning, just for that line:

```
    @dec([i + 5 for i in x]) # pylint: disable=undefined-variable
```

**But I want it now!** (for those who want a 10/10 code rating without cheating)

```
git clone https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid.git
git clone https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint.git
pip install ./astroid/
pip install ./pylint/
pylint --version
```

> pylint 2.5.0-dev1
> astroid 2.4.0

With the development version of Pylint (and Astroid, the library Pylint uses for parsing), the code in the question shouldn't give any `undefined-variable` complaints (though it will give some style warnings). If this ever changes, please reopen the bug report!