# Python: Function scope inside a class

Tags: python, function, class, oop, scope

Let's consider the code below.

```py
name = "John"

class MyClass:
    name = "Tom"
    list_1 = [name] * 2
    list_2 = [name for i in range(2)]
```

On first look, one might expect `list_1` and `list_2` to both have the same
content: `["Tom", "Tom"]`, but this is not the case. `list_1` evaluates to
`["Tom", "Tom"]`, whereas `list_2` evaluates to `["John", "John"]`.

I read that when a function is nested inside a class, Python will use variables defined in the module scope and not in the class scope. `list_1` is not a function, so it uses `name` from the class scope, whereas `list_2` is a function and, therefore, uses `name` from the module scope. I understand this is how it works, but it seems counter-intuitive. I don't understand the reason.

Comment: What are you asking? The reasons *why*? Because python class bodies don't create enclosing scopes, which is why you have to use `self` to, for example, call other methods defined in the class scope. That was the design decision when Guido wrote the language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scoping with list comprehensions takes some getting used to.  In this case, the local scope within the list comprehension `list2 = [name for i in range(2)]` temporarily blocks class local scope.  See: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition).