# list comprehension vs for loop, within class definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Considering the code below:

```py
class Test:
    l = [1, 2, 3]
    foo = lambda x: x

    for x in l:
        print(foo(x))

   [print(foo(x)) for x in l]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
```

The output is the following:

```
1
2
3
... in <listcomp>
    [print(foo(x)) for x in l]
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

I don't understand why isn't `foo` a visible function from within the list iteration. Probably something to do with scopes but I am looking for the right explanation, with documentation to support it if possible.

ps: I am not interested in alternative implementations for the sake of just fixing the code.

Comment: no you can't, then ```x``` would essentially be ```self```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing class variables from a list comprehension in the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition) question seems to pretty much answer the issue and goes a long way to thoroughly explain it. There is however a small variation that can be solved following a similar approach. The resulting code is as follows:

```py
class Test:
    l = [1, 2, 3]
    foo = lambda x: x

    (lambda foo=foo, l=l: [print(foo(x)) for x in l])()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `map` if your desired list comprehension is simple enough:

```
class Test:
    l = [1, 2, 3]
    foo = lambda x: x
    
    list(map(print, map(foo, l)))
```

Outputs

```
1
2
3
```