# NameError during class creation

Tags: python

I have the following code, and I wonder how I can prevent getting error.

```
class A:
    ...:     class Numbers(Enum):
    ...:         ONE = 1
    ...:         TWO = 2
    ...:     ODDS = (Numbers.ONE,)
    ...:     EVENS = [number for number in Numbers if not number in ODDS]
```

After running this snippet, I get `NameError: name 'ODDS' is not defined`.

Then I try to use ODDS as `A.ODDS`

```py
In [71]: class A:
    ...:     class Numbers(Enum):
    ...:         ONE = 1
    ...:         TWO = 2
    ...:     ODDS = (Numbers.ONE,)
    ...:     EVENS = [number for number in Numbers if not number in A.ODDS]
    ...: 

In [72]: A.EVENS
Out[72]: [<Numbers.ONE: 1>, <Numbers.TWO: 2>]
```

However, I only want evens.. So if I try like this, the following happens.

```py
In [76]: class A:
    ...:     class Numbers(Enum):
    ...:         ONE = 1
    ...:         TWO = 2
    ...:     ODDS = (Numbers.ONE,)
    ...:     EVENS = [number for number in A.Numbers if not number in A.ODDS]
    ...: 

In [77]: A.EVENS
Out[77]: [<Numbers.TWO: 2>]
```

Anyone knows why the last way work and previous ones do not?

Thanks

EDIT:

I restarted the shell and tried again

```py
In [4]: class A:
   ...:     class Numbers(Enum):
   ...:         ONE = 1
   ...:         TWO = 2
   ...:     ODDS = (Numbers.ONE,)
   ...:     EVENS = [number for number in A.Numbers if not number in A.ODDS]
```

got `NameError: name 'A' is not defined`

Comment: Yes you are right. I restarted the shell and got `NameError: name 'A' is not defined
` is there any way it would work?

Answer (score 0):

So I found this question on stackoverflow: [Accessing class variables from a list comprehension in the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition)

here, the accepted answer details this pretty nicely. to summarize

> So, to summarize: you cannot access the class scope from functions, list comprehensions or generator expressions enclosed in that scope; they act as if that scope does not exist. In Python 2, list comprehensions were implemented using a shortcut, but in Python 3 they got their own function scope (as they should have had all along) and thus your example breaks.