# choices=Status.choices, NameError: name 'Status' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am receiving a "NameError: name 'Status' is not defined" when trying to run my Django program. This error occurs in my Post model when defining the Status field choices. I am following the Django book in 4 examples by Mele Antonio. Can you help me understand and fix this error?

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):

    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        DRAFT = 'DF', 'Draft'
        PUBLISHED = 'PB', 'Published'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, 
                              choices=Status.choices,
                              default=Status.DRAFT)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-published']
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['-published']),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Note: This question is related to my previous question, and I will apply the solution given there to fix this issue.

Comment: Code looks ok. Can you post entire error trace? Maybe it's somewhere else

Comment: The class name `Status` probably clashes with the attribute name `status`.

Comment: Althoug it does not apply to the OP, a similar `NameError` also arises e.g. if you try to use a [class attribute in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13905741) for `choices`.