# Referring to other class properties in comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension, class-properties

Say I define some class property based on another:

```py
class X:
    foo = 42
    bar = foo + 5

# X.bar == 47
```

this works fine. However, `foo` is not available if I use a list (or dict, etc.) comprehension:

```py
class X:
    foo = 42
    bar = [foo + i for i in range(3)]

# NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

This raises two questions:

1. Why are the `locals()` at the point of assignment of `bar` not passed to the comprehension? (The "class definition" scope behaves a lot like any other scope otherwise (even allowing `if` statements and such) so this surprised me.)
2. Is there an alternative way to reference `foo` in the comprehension? (Note that `X.foo` also causes a `NameError` as `X` is not defined at that point.)

I've tested this on Python 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10 and all behave identically.

Comment: I don't think it's really any nicer than your workaround, but FWIW this works: `f = functools.partial(operator.add, foo); bar = [*map(f, range(3))]`. Similar attempts with `foo` inside the lambda don't work.

Comment: [Maybe in 3.13](https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-709-one-behavior-change-that-was-missed-in-the-pep/26691) (see the first and the last message there).

Comment: To make matters worse, if you happen to have a `foo` defined at global scope for other reasons, it will work, but with the wrong value.

Comment: Whoops, should have searched a little better! Appreciate the comments though.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround I have come up with involves replacing the list comprehension with a `for` loop:

```py
class X:
    foo = 42
    bar = []
    
    for i in range(3):
        bar.append(foo + i)

# X.bar == [42, 43, 44]
```

but I am still interested in more direct answers to the questions raised.

Comment: @tdelaney Or [use a for-clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76622313/12671057) (just added to the other question). Here it would be `bar = [foo + i for foo in [foo] for i in range(3)]`.

Comment: @KellyBundy - Oops, I tested with foo = 0 and didn't notice I was using the same variable twice. So, `bar = (lambda x: [x+i for i in range(3)])(foo)`.