Python failed to initialize a 2d array as class attributes
I am implementing a transition tables as a class attribute with,
class Phase:
    num_states = 15
    transition_table = [[False for _ in range(num_states)] for _ in range(num_states)]

but it failed with NameError: name 'num_states' is not defined.
However, 1d array works as expected,
class Phase:
    num_states = 15
    transition_table = [False for _ in range(num_states)] # this works

I was wondering why this is the case, as num_states is defined before transition_table and it should have access to the previous one?
Edit: this is due to Python's implement of class scopes; Use class attribs in outer scope for loop will not give an error, but inner scope will. There is a link in the comment that explains this in detail.

This is pretty unintuitive for python. There is an answer that explains this pretty well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition

This explains in detail why nested for loop doesn't work! Very nice post, thanks!

It looks like num_states
is out of scope from the class definition. You can workaround this by passing the class variable into a lambda and run the list comprehension inside the lambda
class Phase:
    num_states = 15
    transition_table = (lambda x=num_states: [[False for _ in range(x)] for _ in range(x)])()


@Mark Did you mean [[False for _ in range(Phase.num_states)] for _ in range(Phase.num_states)]? It returns the NameError: name 'Phase' is not defined when I tested it. It looks like class can't reference itself when defining its variable

You are right...sorry — I was in a notebook and failed to clear the earlier state–:face palm:.

This works thanks! I will accept this as the answer.
