# Variables get changed when class has a list comprehension in the definition?

Tags: python

Have a look at this simple Python code:

```
class A:
    x = 123
    y = [(x,x*x) for x in [1,2,3]]

print A().x
```

`A.x` is `123`, but when I do `A().x`, it prints `3`. Why?

```
$ python a.py 
3
```

Comment: In my Python 3.3, it prints 123.

Comment: @mayaa: see the dupe question, this is a Python 2.x problem where variable scope for list comprehensions is handled differently.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That is not the same question. Perhaps the answer covers this question, but that's a lot of bytecode to read through just to find out...

Comment: It is *the same basic problem*.

Comment: And [Python list comprehension rebind names even after scope of comprehension. Is this right?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4198906) is a dupe too, minus the class scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a behaviour related to py2.x. In py2.x the list comprehensions don't have their own scope. So, the list comprehension in your case actually modified the variable `x` and as `x` was assigned the value `3` at the end of list comprehension so you'll get `3` for both `A().x` and `A.x`.

[In py3.x this has been fixed](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax):

> ...and in particular the loop control variables are no longer leaked
>   into the surrounding scope.

Comment: But there's no scope in class definitions? Why would there be one? The only reason I could think of is if you were allowed to do something like `class A: if True: z = 4`.

Comment: @Dog [Classes are namespaces themselves and yes they have scope.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Answer (score 0):

You have overriden the `x` in the list comprehension. Should use another name.