# Django multi-table inheritance chokes on leaked variable in model definition

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, list-comprehension, multi-table-inheritance

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    pass

class RebelliousChild(Parent):
    parent_fields = [__x.name for __x in Parent._meta._fields()]
```

Django **1.3** responds:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field '_RebelliousChild__x' 
in class 'RebelliousChild'clashes with field of similar name from base class 'Parent'
```

Django **1.5** responds:

```
FieldError: Local field u'id' in class 'RebelliousChild' clashes with field 
of similar name from base class 'Parent'
```

My second reaction (after trying to make the variable private) was to delete the variable (which worked.)

```py
parent_fields = [__x.name for __x in Parent._meta._fields()]
del __x
```

---

List comprehensions [leak their control variables in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199355).
Django [prohibits overriding parent field attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted), which seems to be involved somehow, since Django 1.5 has the same issue. But in both cases the leaked attribute name `_RebelliousChild__x` isn't defined on Parent.

What is going on here?

> PS
>   Using "list(x.name for x in Parent._meta._fields())" is prettier than "del x". See the aforementioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199355 about generators not leaking their control variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

In short, you don't need to apply the parent fields to the child(they already exist, but in a different table), you can access them directly on a RebelliousChild instance.