# Python split twice with strip in one line

Tags: python, split, strip

I have a string like this

```
PARAMS = 'TEST = xy; TEST2= klklk '
```

which I want to split twice, once at the ";" and second on the "=" and then put it in a dict.

I can do it with this line:

```
dict(item.split("=") for item in PARAMS.split(";"))
```

and get:

```
{' TEST2': ' klklk ', 'TEST ': ' xy'}
```

I would now also like to strip the key and value before putting them in the dict. Is there an elegant way to do it in one line in python?

Comment: lambda and for loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dict([i.strip() for i in item.split("=")] for item in PARAMS.split(";"))
```

This runs a lot faster than @aIKid's solution :)

```
PARAMS = 'TEST = xy; TEST2= klklk '
from timeit import timeit
print timeit('dict((i.strip() for i in item.split("=")) for item in PARAMS.split(";"))', "from __main__ import PARAMS")
print timeit('dict([i.strip() for i in item.split("=")] for item in PARAMS.split(";"))', "from __main__ import PARAMS")
```

**Output**

```
18.7284784281
9.16360774723
```

Comment: @aIKid: just as with [list comprehensions and `str.join()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/100297), `dict()` *has* to have sequences for each `(key, value)` pair so that their length can be verified. Add to that that in Python 2.7 [list comprehensions don't use a new scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198906/python-list-comprehension-rebind-names-even-after-scope-of-comprehension-is-thi) but generator expressions do (making the fixed costs of a list comp lower), and you'll see why using a list comprehension here for the `(key, value)` pairs is faster.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Woohoo, thanks for the explanation! Will keep that in mind. Thanks again!

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: but in this case not inlining at all is even faster than list comprehension (because the second loop should not be a loop at all, but list comprehension lack necessary syntaxic power).

Comment: @kris: indeed; avoiding loops is faster still. Sometimes a one-liner is just not worth it!

Comment: @kriss How can we do this without the second loop?

Comment: @thefourtheye: the second split should just return key and value, other configurations are errors. We want to strip both, but it's still just two values. But in the list comprehension context we have not much choice but either tricking that to a loop of two (or performing two splits of the same value, which is possibly even worse).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know exactly what you call 'elegant', but this works:

```
dict((i.strip() for i in item.split("=")) for item in PARAMS.split(";"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
dict(map(lambda x: x.strip(), item.split("=")) for item in PARAMS.split(";"))
```

or another even more *elegant* version:

```
dict((l[i].strip(), l[i+1].strip()) for i in range(2) for l in [re.split(';|=', PARAMS)])
```

Of course this is elegant only if you take it as a synonym of *obfuscated*, but when we are seeking one-liners is it not what we mean ?

To solve this problem I would probably write:

```
d = dict(); 
for item in PARAMS.split(";"):
    key, value = item.split("=")
    d[key.strip()] = value.strip()
```

It is both easier to read *and* faster than all the proposed answer until now, and I didn't even bothered to optimize it in any way, henceforth it is probably not the best possible solution.

Don't believe it on words, time the different solutions to check:

```
PARAMS = 'TEST = xy; TEST2= klklk '

from timeit import timeit

print 'obfuscated', timeit('dict((l[i].strip(), l[i+1].strip()) for i in range(2) for l in [re.split(";|=", PARAMS)])', "from __main__ import PARAMS; import re")
print 'tuple', timeit('dict((i.strip() for i in item.split("=")) for item in PARAMS.split(";"))', "from __main__ import PARAMS")
print 'regex', timeit('dict(re.findall(r"(\S+)\s*=\s*([^\s;]+)", PARAMS))', "from __main__ import PARAMS; import re")
print 'lambda', timeit('dict(map(lambda x: x.strip(), item.split("=")) for item in PARAMS.split(";"))', "from __main__ import PARAMS; import re")
print 'list comprehension', timeit('dict([i.strip() for i in item.split("=")] for item in PARAMS.split(";"))', "from __main__ import PARAMS")
print 'replace spaces', timeit('dict(item.split("=") for item in PARAMS.replace(" ", "").split(";"))', "from __main__ import PARAMS; import re")

print 'not one line', timeit(
'''
    d = dict(); 
    for item in PARAMS.split(";"):
        key, value = item.split("=")
        d[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    d
''',
"from __main__ import PARAMS")
```

Below are the timing results:

- obfuscated:         7.36826086044
- tuple:              4.49374079704
- regex:              3.61684799194
- lambda:             3.51627087593
- list comprehension: 2.90777206421
- replace spaces:     2.46001887321
- not one line:       1.71015286446

It speaks for itself.

PS: the reason why the not one line is faster is probably because it avoids creating an unecessary list structure, but directly store value in the dict. But that was a no brainer, not even voluntary.

Answer (score 1):

Or, alternatively:

```
import re
text = 'TEST = xy; TEST2= klklk '
params = dict(re.findall(r'(\S+)\s*=\s*([^\s;]+)', text))
# {'TEST': 'xy', 'TEST2': 'klklk'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If none of your keys or values have spaces inside them, then you're free to eliminate *all* spaces with a single `replace` method:

```
>>> dict(item.split("=") for item in PARAMS.replace(" ", "").split(";"))
{'TEST': 'xy', 'TEST2': 'klklk'}
```

This will eliminate more spaces than `strip` would, of course:

```
>>> PARAMS = 'TEST 3 = there should be spaces between these words '
>>> dict(item.split("=") for item in PARAMS.replace(" ", "").split(";"))
{'TEST3': 'thereshouldbespacesbetweenthesewords'}
```