# Scope of class variable with list comprehension

Tags: python, scope, list-comprehension

have a look at the following piece of code:

```
class a:
    s = 'python'
    b = ['p', 'y']
    c = [x for x in s]
```

the output:

```
>>> a.c
['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

but when i try to limit the list with if:

```
class a:
    s = 'python'
    b = ['p', 'y']
    c = [x for x in s if x in b]
```

Shows the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    class a:
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 4, in a
    c = [x for x in s if x in b]
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 4, in <listcomp>
    c = [x for x in s if x in b]
NameError: global name 'b' is not defined
```

If a make `global b` it works, why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't so much about the variable scope in list comprehensions as about the way classes work. In Python 3 ([but not in Python 2!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199355/2588818)), list comprehensions don't affect the scope around them:

```
>>> [i for i in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> i
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
>>> i = 0
>>> [i for i in range(10)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> i
0
```

However, when you do that in a class, it won't look for `b` among the class attributes the way it would in the local scope of a module or function. To do what you are trying to do, use the `@property` decorator:

```
>>> class a:
...   s = 'python'
...   b = 'py'
...   @property
...   def c(self):
...     return [x for x in self.s if x in self.b]
... 
>>> A = a()
>>> A.c
['p', 'y']
```

Also, remember that strings are iterable too (they're just lists of their component characters), so no need to explicitly make `b` a list.

Comment: Thank you!! b is a list above cause it will have not precisely a string :D thanks again!!!

Comment: @grkiran2011 (new user) raised the following question: _Sorry but could not understand the explanation provided. I mean how can the list comprehension see the string s, but not the list b. Could you please clarify._

Comment: @kvantour the contexts are slightly different: in the part where it "zooms" on a specific element it doesn't see the stuff from the enclosing scope (that's the `if ...` part here). It however does see those external variables where the list comprehension is fed the container to work with.