# Python redeclared variable defined before in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

After having written this piece of code to execute queries on database separately, *PyCharm* highlighted the second *i* with the given comment.

```
for i in range(records):
    filler.apply_proc('AddCompany', gen_add_company())

for i in range(records):
    filler.apply_proc('AddConference', gen_add_conference())
```

> Redeclared 'i' defined above without usage.

Could it be subject of any error? Should I achieve it in other way?

Comment: use `_` instead of i for throw away variables... but its not an error ... its fine ... pycharm is just warning you

Comment: @JoranBeasley, any reason why you're supposed to use _ instead of i? Just curious :)

Comment: its just convention ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is the different scoping than you would get in, say, C++/Java. There you'd expect `i` not to exist between `for`s. [It's not the case.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops)

You could see that in work, assuming records == 10:

```
for i in range(records):
    filler.apply_proc('AddCompany', gen_add_company())

print("i: %d" % i)

for i in range(records):
    filler.apply_proc('AddConference', gen_add_conference())
```

You'd get in your output - assuming no output from `for`:

```
i: 9
```

The reason why you're getting the warning is probably that this kind of thing could lead to brain-cracking bugs. Indirect solutions are included in the linked page; one you could consider is to encase your `for` in a function, which might be especially good for readability if this happens more than twice.

There's also a similar case of scoping surprise in [list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198906/python-list-comprehension-rebind-names-even-after-scope-of-comprehension-is-thi), but not in Python 3 you're asking about.