# How to save repeated computation in list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

In the following Python code:

```
keyboards = [3, 1]
drivers = [5, 2, 8]
upper_limit = 10
sums = [k + d for k in keyboards for d in drivers if (k + d) <= upper_limit]
```

I'd like to store the result of `k+d` in the list comprehension so that it can be referred in the list comprehension. Is it possible in Python3?

I know that we can do the following:

```
sums = []
for k in keyboards:
    for d in drivers:
        s = k + d
        if s <= upper_limit:
            sums.append(s)
```

But I wish to avoid the side effect operation of append.

Comment: Just stumbled on a duplicate for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3.8 and above, you can use the walrus operator for this:

```
sums = [s for k in keyboards for d in drivers if (s := k + d) <= upper_limit]
```

The performance advantage appears to be slight for this example:

```
$ python -m timeit "[s for k in range(1000) for d in range(1000) if (s := k + d) <= 1000]"
5 loops, best of 5: 72.5 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "[k + d for k in range(1000) for d in range(1000) if k + d <= 1000]"
5 loops, best of 5: 75.6 msec per loop
```

The `k + d` computation would, presumably, have to be a lot more complex to show a major benefit.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Python 3.8 or newer, you can use the [assignment operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions) (a.k.a. the *walrus operator*) to create a new local name and assign to it, inside a list comprehension. For your specific example, you'd do that in the left-hand operand for the `<=` comparison:

```
sums = [
    s
    for k in keyboards
    for d in drivers
    if (s := k + d) <= upper_limit
]
```

Note that you have to use parentheses around the assignment here, as the walrus operator has [the lowest precedence of all Python operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence); without parentheses you'd be assigning the result of `k + d <= upper_limit` to `s`, so a boolean value.

Take into account that `s` **will be visible in the surrounding scope**, the name `s` will have the same scope as `sums` has; local inside a function, global if you run the list comprehension at the module level. `k` and `d`, on the other hand, are local to the list comprehension loop, and are not visible outside of the comprehension.

Demo:

```
>>> keyboards = [3, 1]
>>> drivers = [5, 2, 8]
>>> upper_limit = 10
>>> [s for k in keyboards for d in drivers if (s := k + d) <= upper_limit]
[8, 5, 6, 3, 9]
>>> s
9
>>> k
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

In earlier Python versions, only names in the target of `for` loops  can be used to assign to a new name in a list comprehension, so if you need a 'local' variable to reference a calculation, you need to find ways to add an extra loop.

So in Python 3.7 or older, you can add another loop over a single element tuple that calculates `k + d`:

```
sums = [
    s
    for k in keyboards
    for d in drivers
    for s in (k + d,)
    if s <= upper_limit
]
```

`(k + d,)` is a [single-element tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), and so the `for s in (k + d,)` execute exactly once for each iteration over `keyboards` and `drivers`, effectively assigning `k + d` to `s`.

You could also use a generator expression to produce `k + d` sums for the two nested `for` loops, then iterate over the results of that expression:

```
sums = [
    s
    for s in (
        k + d
        for k in keyboards
        for d in drivers
    )
    if s <= upper_limit
]
```

In the latter case you can store that expression as a separate variable first:

```
s_calc = (k + d for k in keyboards for d in drivers)
sums = [s for s in s_calc if s <= upper_limit]
```

With these options, `s` is always local to the comprehension loop and is not visible at the `sums` scope level. It doesn't 'bleed' out of the comprehension expression.

Demo of the latter options:

```
>>> [s for k in keyboards for d in drivers for s in (k + d,) if s <= upper_limit]
[8, 5, 6, 3, 9]
>>> [s for s in (k + d for k in keyboards for d in drivers) if s <= upper_limit]
[8, 5, 6, 3, 9]
>>> s_calc = (k + d for k in keyboards for d in drivers)
>>> [s for s in s_calc if s <= upper_limit]
[8, 5, 6, 3, 9]
```

Comment: @agtoever: for the given sample input, the single-tuple loop is slightly faster (1.11s vs 1.26s for 1 million iterations). I haven't tested with larger inputs.

Comment: In CPython 3.9+, "effectively assigning k + d to s" really means "assigning k + d to s" (without building a tuple and without iterating).

Comment: @KellyBundy: yes, in terms of the generated bytecode, the single-iteration `for` loop bytecodes have been optimised away. Interestingly enough, the walrus operator results in `s` being treated as a _global_ rather than a local. If the comprehension loop is in a function scope, it is a non-local variable, meaning it is part of the function scope.