# finding words from an array, in a string

Tags: python

I'm using a twitter API and are scanning tweets to see if they contain a word which is in an array named 'special'. The following code appears to work fine, but only indicates when it finds a match. How do I also get it to show both the particular word that matched, and the string that the word was contained in?

```
if any(word in tweet.body for word in special):
                print "match found"
```

What I'd like is something along the lines of "the word BOB was found in the tweet 'I am BOB'"

Cheers

Comment: Just write the obvious `for` loop yourself, so you can access the found keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for word in special:
    if word in tweet.body:
        print "Matched {0}. In string: {1}.".format(word, tweet.body)
```

Updated snippet as per request in comment

```
import re

word = 'one'
result = re.search(r'\b'+ word + r'\b', 'phone hello')
if result:
    print "Found!"
else:
    print "No Match!!!"
```

**Result:**

```
No Match!!!
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well. Is there an easy way of having this match only exact matches (short of using regex?). I notice that the special word 'one' will match in 'phone' etc

Comment: Updated solution. Use regex to match exact text. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code will print all matched words for given tweet.

```
def find_words_in_tweet(tweet, words):
    return [word for word in words if word in tweet]

special = ['your', 'words']
for tweet in tweets:
    words = find_words_in_tweet(tweet.body, special)
    print "Matched words: {words} in tweet: {tweet}.".format(
        words=words.join(', '), tweet=tweet.body
    )
```

Comment: That won't work. The name `word` is [not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198906/python-list-comprehension-rebind-names-even-after-scope-of-comprehension-is-thi/4199355#4199355) in the scope of the `print` statement (at least in my Python version, 2.7.13, and definitely not in Python 3). And if it were, I think it would only print the first word of all that matched.

Comment: True, I was too hasty. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

## Use regx appropriately

```
import re

for word in special:
    reg_object = re.search(word, tweet_body, re.IGNORECASE)
    if reg_object:
        print(reg_object.group(), word) # this will get you the exact string 
        # That matched in the tweet body and your key string.
```

use re.IGNORECASE only if you need case insensitive search.