# comprehension list in python2 works fine but i get an error in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have the following code using the comprehensive list:

```
x = int ( input())  
y = int ( input()) 
z = int ( input())
n = int ( input()) 


ret_list = [ (x,y,z) for x in range(x+1) for y in range(y+1) for z in 
range(z+1) if x+y+z!=n ]
print(ret_list)
```

in python2 works as expected. However in python3 i get the following error:

```
print([ (x,y,z) for x in range(x+1) for y in range(y+1) for z in range(z+1) if 
x+y+z!=n ])
File "tester.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
print([ (x,y,z) for x in range(x+1) for y in range(y+1) for z in range(z+1) if 
x+y+z!=n ])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment
```

I am just curious what I am doing wrong. I might be missing something in Python3 although it works fantastic in python2. Thank you.

Comment: why reusing the x,y,z variables in your comprehension? just pick some other variable names. It has to do with scope difference in comprehensions between python 2 and 3.

Comment: but i need them to create the range and the conditional.

Answer (score 2):

Since `x` `y` and `z` are defined as "local" variables in the list comprehension, Python 3 considers them as such, and doesn't use/see the global value.

Python 2 doesn't make that difference (hence the variable "leak" that some have observed when exiting a comprehension) and it behaves exactly like if you used normal loops

This is better explained here: [Python list comprehension rebind names even after scope of comprehension. Is this right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198906/python-list-comprehension-rebind-names-even-after-scope-of-comprehension-is-thi)

What is really funny is that python complains about `y` first and not `x`. Well, since I'm curious I've asked this question here: [why the UnboundLocalError occurs on the second variable of the flat comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719830/why-the-unboundlocalerror-occurs-on-the-second-variable-of-the-flat-comprehensio)

The proper way to do this is to use different variable names for your loop indices (not sure if the names I chose are very good, but at least this works regardless of the python version):

```
ret_list = [ (x1,y1,z1) for x1 in range(x+1) for y1 in range(y+1) for z1 in range(z+1) if x1+y1+z1!=n ]
```