# Why does the UnboundLocalError occur on the second variable of the flat comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, list-comprehension

I answered a question here: [comprehension list in python2 works fine but i get an error in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719472/comprehension-list-in-python2-works-fine-but-i-get-an-error-in-python3)

OP's error was using the same variables for max range and indices:

```
x = 12
y = 10
z = 12
n = 100

ret_list = [ (x,y,z) for x in range(x+1) for y in range(y+1) for z in range(z+1) if x+y+z!=n ]
```

This is a Python-3 error only, and related to the scopes that were added to the comprehension to avoid the variables defined here "leaking". Changing the variable names fixes that.

The error is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment
```

because outer, global `y` is shadowed by the local scope.

My question is: why do I get the error on `y` and not on `z` or `x` ?

EDIT: If I remove the loop on `x`, the error moves to `z`:

```
>> ret_list = [ (x,y,z) for y in range(y+1) for z in range(z+1) if x+y+z!=n ]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment
```

If I just do one loop:

```
ret_list = [ (x,y,z) for y in range(y+1) if x+y+z!=n ]
```

it works. So I'm suspecting that the first `range` function is evaluated *before* all the other expressions, which leaves the value of `x` intact. But the exact reason is still to be found. Using Python 3.4.3.

Comment: This is weird on so many levels. No matter what I changed (different combinations of global vars definition order, the order of the variables in the tuple and the order of the for loops) the error stays the same.

Comment: I thought that `range(x+1)` was evaluated first, and x afterwards which would have "delayed" the error on y but that makes no sense since it should be the same for `y`...

Comment: Note that `[x for x in range(x)]` produces no unbound local error. If you look at the output of `dis.dis(compile(src, '<string>', 'eval'))` you can see that `range(x)` is passed to list comprehension as an argument. This means the list comprehension never has to load `x` before it is assigned to. Due to the repeated invocations of `range(y)` this is not true for `y` and so `y` must be first read in side the comprehension. Seems like a possible bug in python.

Comment: It's an explanation, but I don't think it's an answer. The behaviour is counter-intuitive and I want to go see if it's already in the python bug tracker first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behaviour is (implicitly) described in the [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) (emphasis mine).

> However, aside from the iterable expression in the leftmost `for` clause, the comprehension is executed in a separate implicitly nested scope. This ensures that names assigned to in the target list don’t “leak” into the enclosing scope.
>
> **The iterable expression in the leftmost `for` clause is evaluated directly in the enclosing scope and then passed as an argument to the implictly [sic] nested scope.** Subsequent `for` clauses and any filter condition in the leftmost `for` clause cannot be evaluated in the enclosing scope as they may depend on the values obtained from the leftmost iterable. For example: `[x*y for x in range(10) for y in range(x, x+10)]`.

This means that:

```
list_ = [(x, y) for x in range(x) for y in range(y)]
```

equivalent to:

```
def f(iter_):
    for x in iter_:
        for y in range(y):
            yield x, y

list_ = list(f(iter(range(x))))
```

As the name `x` in for the leftmost iterable is read in the enclosing scope as opposed to the nested scope then there is no name conflict between these two uses of `x`. The same is not true for `y`, which is why it is where the `UnboundLocalError` occurs.

As to why this happens: a list comprehension is more-or-less syntactic sugar for `list(<generator expression>)`, so it's going to be using the same code path as a generator expression (or at least behave in the same way). Generator expressions evaluate the iterable expression in the leftmost `for` clause to make error handling when the generator expression somewhat saner. Consider the following code:

```
y = None                             # line 1
gen = (x + 1 for x in range(y + 1))  # line 2
item = next(gen)                     # line 3
```

`y` is clearly the wrong type and so the addition will raise a `TypeError`. By evaluating `range(y + 1)` immediately that type error is raised on line 2 rather than line 3. Thus, it is easier to diagnose where and why the problem occurred. Had it occurred on line 3 then you might mistakenly assume that it was the `x + 1` statement that caused the error.

There is a bug report [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue31126) that mentions this behaviour. It was resolved as "not a bug" for reason that it is desirable that list comprehensions and generator expressions have the same behaviour.